# Formatting the date time with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a date/time string like `2012-01-13 04:37:20` but I want to convert it to `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm`, how can i do this?

I am using the following code but it throws an exception.

```
var now = "2012-01-13 04:37:20";
var dd = now.toLocaleDateString() + " " + now.toLocaleTimeString();
alert(dd);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a simple string manipulation and create a `JavaScript` date object. See function below, which accepts date in format: `//yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

[Fiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/dV8RQ/2/)

**The Script:**

```js
function toJSDate(dateTime) {
  var dateTime = dateTime.split(" "); // dateTime[0] = date, dateTime[1] = time

  var date = dateTime[0].split("-");
  var time = dateTime[1].split(":");


  // month is 0 indexed so date[1] - 1 corrected format
  // (year,    month,       day,     hours,   minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
  return new Date(date[0], date[1] - 1, date[2], time[0], time[1], time[2], 0);
}
```

Comment: `date[1]` should be `date[1] - 1` for correct output of month.

Answer (score 7):

The best date-time handling lib in JavaSCript is [moment.](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need all the features that a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) provides, then you can use my port of [strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). It's lightweight (1.35 KB vs. 57.9 KB minified compared to Moment.js 2.15.0) and provides most of the functionality of `strftime()`.

```
/* Port of strftime(). Compatibility notes:
 *
 * %c - formatted string is slightly different
 * %D - not implemented (use "%m/%d/%y" or "%d/%m/%y")
 * %e - space is not added
 * %E - not implemented
 * %h - not implemented (use "%b")
 * %k - space is not added
 * %n - not implemented (use "\n")
 * %O - not implemented
 * %r - not implemented (use "%I:%M:%S %p")
 * %R - not implemented (use "%H:%M")
 * %t - not implemented (use "\t")
 * %T - not implemented (use "%H:%M:%S")
 * %U - not implemented
 * %W - not implemented
 * %+ - not implemented
 * %% - not implemented (use "%")
 *
 * strftime() reference:
 * http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html
 *
 * Day of year (%j) code based on Joe Orost's answer:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619879/javascript-calculate-the-day-of-the-year-1-366
 *
 * Week number (%V) code based on Taco van den Broek's prototype:
 * http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/33796/14863/calculate-iso-8601-week-and-year-in-javascript.html
 */
function strftime(sFormat, date) {
  if (!(date instanceof Date)) date = new Date();
  var nDay = date.getDay(),
    nDate = date.getDate(),
    nMonth = date.getMonth(),
    nYear = date.getFullYear(),
    nHour = date.getHours(),
    aDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    aMonths = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    aDayCount = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334],
    isLeapYear = function() {
      return (nYear%4===0 && nYear%100!==0) || nYear%400===0;
    },
    getThursday = function() {
      var target = new Date(date);
      target.setDate(nDate - ((nDay+6)%7) + 3);
      return target;
    },
    zeroPad = function(nNum, nPad) {
      return ('' + (Math.pow(10, nPad) + nNum)).slice(1);
    };
  return sFormat.replace(/%[a-z]/gi, function(sMatch) {
    return {
      '%a': aDays[nDay].slice(0,3),
      '%A': aDays[nDay],
      '%b': aMonths[nMonth].slice(0,3),
      '%B': aMonths[nMonth],
      '%c': date.toUTCString(),
      '%C': Math.floor(nYear/100),
      '%d': zeroPad(nDate, 2),
      '%e': nDate,
      '%F': date.toISOString().slice(0,10),
      '%G': getThursday().getFullYear(),
      '%g': ('' + getThursday().getFullYear()).slice(2),
      '%H': zeroPad(nHour, 2),
      '%I': zeroPad((nHour+11)%12 + 1, 2),
      '%j': zeroPad(aDayCount[nMonth] + nDate + ((nMonth>1 && isLeapYear()) ? 1 : 0), 3),
      '%k': '' + nHour,
      '%l': (nHour+11)%12 + 1,
      '%m': zeroPad(nMonth + 1, 2),
      '%M': zeroPad(date.getMinutes(), 2),
      '%p': (nHour<12) ? 'AM' : 'PM',
      '%P': (nHour<12) ? 'am' : 'pm',
      '%s': Math.round(date.getTime()/1000),
      '%S': zeroPad(date.getSeconds(), 2),
      '%u': nDay || 7,
      '%V': (function() {
              var target = getThursday(),
                n1stThu = target.valueOf();
              target.setMonth(0, 1);
              var nJan1 = target.getDay();
              if (nJan1!==4) target.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4-nJan1)+7)%7);
              return zeroPad(1 + Math.ceil((n1stThu-target)/604800000), 2);
            })(),
      '%w': '' + nDay,
      '%x': date.toLocaleDateString(),
      '%X': date.toLocaleTimeString(),
      '%y': ('' + nYear).slice(2),
      '%Y': nYear,
      '%z': date.toTimeString().replace(/.+GMT([+-]\d+).+/, '$1'),
      '%Z': date.toTimeString().replace(/.+\((.+?)\)$/, '$1')
    }[sMatch] || sMatch;
  });
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
// Returns "15-09-2016 16:20"
strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M');

// You can optionally pass it a Date object
// Returns "01-01-2016 21:30"
strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', new Date('Jan 1, 2016 9:30 PM'));
```

The latest code is available here: https://github.com/thdoan/strftime

Answer (score 5):

Use either simple string manipulation (as suggested by @SKS) or use a library. The latter is more flexible and lets you change the input or output format easily. For example, using the [Globalize.js](http://blog.jquery.com/2015/04/23/announcing-globalize-1-0/) library, you would write:

```
var dd = Globalize.parseDate(now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dd = Globalize.format(dd, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

Note however that formats such as "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm" are confusing – it is neither a standard ISO format nor any localized (language-dependent) format. The Globalize.js library lets you use predefined language-dependent formats in addition to explicitly specified formats.

Note that the built-in date and time parsing and formatting routines in JavaScript are implementation-dependent. Using them means non-portable code. For example, there is no guarantee that `new Date()` will accept the format you have as input, and toLocaleDateString() writes the date in some locale-dependent format, which can be just about anything.

Answer (score 4):

A small but effective function, as follows:

```
var formatTime = function(time, format){
    time = typeof time == 'number' ? new Date(time) : time;
    format = format || 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss';
    var add0 = function(t){ return t < 10 ? '0' + t : t; };
    var year = time.getFullYear();
    var month = time.getMonth() + 1; // 0 indexed
    var date = time.getDate();
    var hours = time.getHours();
    var minutes = time.getMinutes();
    var seconds = time.getSeconds();
    var replaceMent = {
        'yyyy': year,
        'mm': add0(month),
        'm': month,
        'dd': add0(date),
        'd': date,
        'hh': add0(hours),
        'h': hours,
        'MM': add0(minutes),
        'M': minutes,
        'ss': add0(seconds),
        's': seconds
    }
    for(var key in replaceMent){
        format = format.replace(key, replaceMent[key]);
    }
    return format;
}
```

Example usage:

```
// As Date Input
formatTime(new Date()); // 2020-12-10 16:29:32
// As Date Input
formatTime(new Date(),"yyyy-mm-dd"); // 2020-12-10
// OR
formatTime(new Date(),"hh:MM:ss"); // 16:29:32
// As Time Input
formatTime(new Date().getTime()); // 2020-12-10 16:29:32
// OR
formatTime(1607606809630); // 2020-12-10 16:29:32
// OR
formatTime(1607606809630,"yyyy-mm-dd"); // 2020-12-10
// OR
formatTime(1607606809630,"hh:MM:ss"); // 16:29:32
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is best to use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` class.

The usage is fairly straightforward. You can not enter a pattern as you want to, but it will give you the results you want.

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
public formatDate(date : Date) : string{
    var options = {  year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE', options).format(date);
}
```

If you really want to enter a DateTimeFormat string, it would be easy enough to write a function which parses the string using Regex, but I don't think it is needed.

For further Information go here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: Good to know that this exists, but this is not available on all platforms as described in the mozilla reference

Answer (score 2):

For working with DateTimes in javascript it's better to use the 'Intl.DateTimeFormat' as follow:

```
var date = new Date('2012-01-13 14:37:20');
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit',
hour:'2-digit', minute: '2-digit',hour12: false};
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date).replace(/\//g,'-').replace(',',''));
```

Result: "01-13-2012 14:37"

The date and time formats can be customized with options argument.

[Check Online](https://jsbin.com/hezebubuwa/4/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Date requires Date object so you should give var d = new Date() something like this
then for formatting see http://code.google.com/p/datejs/ link it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Love one liners - local date SPACE time DOT milliseconds / IIFE:

```js
// simpler, but milliseconds not padded
console.log(
(function(d){return d.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + d.toLocaleTimeString() + '.' + d.getMilliseconds()})(new Date())
)

// including millis padding
console.log(
(function(d){return d.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + d.toLocaleTimeString() + '.' + (d.getMilliseconds()+1000+'').substr(1)})(new Date())
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your variable now is a `String` object and `toLocaleDateString` method needs a `Date` object. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toLocaleDateString.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Easily accomplished by my [date-shortcode](https://github.com/kodie/date-shortcode) package:

```
const dateShortcode = require('date-shortcode')
dateShortcode.parse('{DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm}', '2012-01-13 04:37:20')
//=> '13-01-2012 04:37'
```

Answer (score -1):

With Jquery, you steal datepicker's feature like that:

```html
$.datepicker.formatDate( "dd-M-yy", new Date())
```

Comment: Nice idea when you don't want to add moment.js, but you already have datepicker at your disposal!