# Need to reduce javascript method code for geting date format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, datetime-format

I am new to javascript.
I used following method to get date time.

```
function getDateTime() {
var now     = new Date(); 
var year    = now.getFullYear();
var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
var day     = now.getDate();
var hour    = now.getHours();
var minute  = now.getMinutes();
var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
if(month.toString().length == 1) {
    var month = '0'+month;
}
if(day.toString().length == 1) {
    var day = '0'+day;
}   
if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
    var hour = '0'+hour;
}
if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
    var minute = '0'+minute;
}
if(second.toString().length == 1) {
    var second = '0'+second;
}   
var dateTime = day+'-'+month+'-'+year+' '+hour+':'+minute;   
 return dateTime;
```

}

I want output like :

```
 day+'-'+month+'-'+year+' '+hour+':'+minute;
```

What is the best method for this

Comment: Use `momentjs` (http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I am not using javascript into browser. so no support for momentjs.Thanks.

Comment: @AndroEmbedded you can use `momentjs` for `node.js` also

Comment: This is also discussed on the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to format date and time in Javascript is to use [this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) lib. It's very simple to use.

```
var now = new Date();
dateFormat(now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:MM:ss");
alert(now);
```