# Change value format of a html5 Time Input

Tags: html, forms, time

I'm trying to figure out if I can change the way a HTML5 Time input passes its value. I have the following form:

```
<form action="action_page.php">
   Select a time:
   <input type="time" name="usr_time">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If I enter, for example, "8:00PM" it returns the following value:

> 20:00

Is there a way to change the way the value comes out to produce the following:

> 8:00PM

Or perhaps even just

> 8:00

Thanks,

Connor

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time

Comment: As Anthony Quinn posted [this thread][1] provides a solution, my bad! 


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time

Answer (score 0):

With html5 is not possible. Try to convert with js.