# Get Current Date/Time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to get the current date and time javascript in the following format

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

But cannot work out how to do it.

```
var d = new Date();
timesheetGrid.cellById(rId,15).setValue(d);
```

This is where I am using the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By format you mean YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: Yes thanks will change that now.

Comment: try this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time

Comment: and where does "current" appear in either the question or the answer? (Date.now() will get it and it's a misnomer as it gets you current time too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about simply:

```
d.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').replace(/\..*$/, '');
```

Take the ISO string, replace the "T" with a space, and trim off the milliseconds.