# How to change date in jquery based on other date

Tags: php, jquery, forms, datetime

I have a simple PHP FORM:

```
<form>
  Date of dispatch<br>
  <input type="datetime" name="date_dispatch" id="date_dispatch" value="2016-04-26 10:00:00"><br>
  Expected delivery timne<br>
  <input type="datetime" name="date_delivery" id="date_delivery">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

User can specify first date (when to collect a parcel) and the second field should be a date of expected delivery. However delivery time can't be earlier than 3 hors later then collet time.
How to use a AJAX/JQUERY to change the value of *date_delivery* to automatically calculated based on *date_dispatch* +3 hours.

I am trying some tests but without a result:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#date_dispatch').change(function() {
    document.getElementById('date_delivery').value = 'test';
  });

});
```

This is my test fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xr7cm6w7/

Will appreciate any help

Comment: ajax is for communicating with a server. you just want javascript (with possibly jquery layered on top).

Comment: ok, thank you for clarification

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use AJAX as long as you want to display this value only.
Use the javascript Date object on the first input change function

[here sth more about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that handles it using jQUery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#date_dispatch').change(function() {
    // Get current dispatch time
    var time = new Date($('#date_dispatch').val());

    // Add 3 hours
    time.setTime(time.setHours(time.getHours()+3));

    // Set delivery time
    $('#date_delivery').val(time.toString());
  });
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mewcg3zo/10/

You'll notice the formatting isn't the same, you'll have to do some extra work to get the date string back to how you want it.  You can look here for some tips on how to do that.  [Javascript format date / time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time)

Comment: Hello, thanx for contribution but this is not working, when I am changing the first date I can see only text in second field 'Invalid Date', instead of date (even in other date format). Or this need to be modified first to change the date?

Comment: It works, but there are some things you'll need to check for validation.  An empty string, letters or even just a time like 1:00 PM won't work with this implementation.

Comment: I am just changing an hour: "2016-04-26 10:00:00" to for example "2016-04-26 11:00:00" and can see only an 'invalid date'

Comment: Does it work for you in jsfiddle? If it does it must be something locally.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Safari on MacOS and this is not working in jfiddle. I've tried also a Firefox - the same.

Comment: Looks like there can be some issues with Date on Safari.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari

Comment: Hello again. I've just tried your dolution on my PC with FIrefox, and works fine :-)
But on MacOS (both Firefox and Safari) won't work.
Thank you for contribution.