# Get formatted day and time using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

I have an input field which stores data in format

```
28 Oct 2016 10:50 pm
```

I need to send the values to server in different format, I just need to send day of week and time in `22:50:00` format.

Output required:

```
var dayOfWeek =  6 // (or friday); 
var time = 22:50:00;
```

I am struggling to do it in a simple and neat way.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript format date / time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time)

Comment: creating a new date object by parsing the input

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d6chmdbu/

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks, it is just what I need

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```js
(function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date("28 Oct 2016 10:50 pm");
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";
   var form="";
    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
  var time = d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes();
  if(d.getHours() > 12)
    {form = "pm"}else{form ="am"}
   console.log( n+'    '+time+form);
})()
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Missing time part.

Comment: see the updated answer .all fields are added as per your requirement

Answer (score 4):

If you can do it on server side: check strtotime() for php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
var_dump(date('l H:i:s', strtotime('28 Oct 2016 10:50 pm')));
```

This will return string(11) "Friday 22:50:00"

Comment: He has to send it to server. Which means he is giving option to change date. So no. This cannot be used

Answer (score 0):

> If you want your expected `days of month` and `time`(24 hour format)
>   Then try it:

```js
var dt = new Date("28 Oct 2016 10:50 pm");
var day = dt.getDay();  //days of the week

alert("Days of the week: "+day);

var time = fixLength(dt.getHours())+":"+fixLength(dt.getMinutes())+":"+fixLength(dt.getSeconds());

alert("Time: "+time);



function fixLength(x){
   return (x<10?'0':'')+x; 
}
```