# JavaScript Datetime formatting

Tags: javascript

I have the below Data Format which I need to format to dd-mm-yyyy or dddd-mm-yyy. What would be the best way of doing so in JavaScript?

```
Fri Jun 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Comment: how about using [this](https://momentjs.com/) library

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
new Date(2017, 03, 07).toString(); // ""Fri Apr 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

[image]

Comment: @Dinistro For more additional date formats specific to region u can use moment js otherwise u can use the above one

Comment: I dont understand how new Date(2017, 03, 07).toString(); works here?

Comment: @Jaron787 see my edited answer with screenshot it works !!!

Comment: I'm wanting to change my format from Fri Apr 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to 2017, 03, 07 not the other way round

Comment: @Jaron787 Try this
var a = moment().format('YYYY DD MM')
console.log(a); // 2017 07 03