# Datetime format conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

How to change this **27 June 2018 - 05:25** into **Y-m-d H:i:s** format?
I don't know how and I'm just a beginner in javascript, can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: @RumitPatel I visited that link awhile ago but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using moment.js you can parse and format:

```
var dateStr = moment('27 June 2018 - 05:25', 'DD MMM YYYY - HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(dateStr);
```

Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z7jz5y8t/1/

Comment: in your fiddle, I change the date into 'inputDate' variable and the result is : Formatted date: Invalid date

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to a new one: https://jsfiddle.net/z7jz5y8t/1/, give this a go!

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom format like this

```html
function formatDate(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return date.getFullYear() + "-"+ (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate()  + " " + strTime;
}

var d = new Date();
var e = formatDate(d);
alert(e);
```

Also possible duplicate of this '[Javascript format date / time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time)'