# Javascript timestamp string to datetime and operate it

Tags: javascript

I have an arry of strings like this "2020-04-22T09:05:28.774000+00:00", how can I convert this to a datetime and operate it with the current time? Thank you for the help

Comment: use `moment.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let list = ["2020-04-22T09:05:28.774000+00:00","2020-03-22T09:05:28.774000+00:00"]
let diff = [];
for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
     diff.push(new Date() - Date.parse(list[i]));
console.log(diff)
```

Comment: What time format is the answer in?

Comment: It returns the number of ms since you did not specify a specific time format. You can reference to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time in order get your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as an argument to `new Date(string)`, since your string is a valid ISO format into a `Date object`. You can also use `Date.parse(string)`, which will convert it to a UTC timestamp:

```js
// Returns Date obkect
console.log(new Date('2020-04-22T09:05:28.774000+00:00'));

// Returns ms elapsed since unix epoch
console.log(Date.parse('2020-04-22T09:05:28.774000+00:00'));
```