# in javascript, how can i use this 2021-01-27T14:29:22.723782Z with date object?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a backend responding with this date format, when i use it with date object in javascript, i get an error saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

how can i get date from it in DD/MM/YYYY:MM:SS ?

```js
new Date(2021-01-27T14:29:22.723782Z)
```

Comment: Formatting *might* have been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date) (about 4,500 times apparently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotations "" or '': `new Date('xxxxxx')`

```js
const targetDate = new Date('2021-01-27T14:29:22.723782Z');
console.log(targetDate);

function formatDate(d) {
  const year = d.getFullYear();
  const month = String(d.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  const date = String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  const hr = String(d.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
  const min = String(d.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
  const sec = String(d.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');

  return `${date}/${month}/${year} ${hr}:${min}:${sec}`;
}

console.log(formatDate(targetDate));
```

| Description | JS | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Year | `.getFullYear()` |  |
| Month | `.getMonth()` | January -> `0` |
| Date | `.getDate()` |  |
| Hours | `.getHours()` |  |
| Minutes | `.getMinutes()` |  |
| Seconds | `.getSeconds()` |  |
| Convert a value to a string | `String(xxxx)` |  |
| A length of a string becomes 2. If an original strings shorter than 2, 0 fills the length | `.padStart(2, '0')` | `'98'`->`'98'` / `'2'` -> `'02'` |

---

**Another solution**

```js
const targetDate = new Date('2021-01-27T14:29:22.723782Z');
console.log(targetDate);

function formatDate(d) {
  const options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
  };
  
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('id-ID', options).format(d).replace(/\./g, ':');
}

console.log(formatDate(targetDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Input to Date should be string here.

```
new Date("2021-01-27T14:29:22.723782Z") // Wed Jan 27 2021 19:59:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

And to format date, you can look for moment.js library or can do it manually.

Refer this answer: [Javascript format date / time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time)