# Time Format not working for dateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

I downloaded the javascript and required css files from 
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

I am getting the date and time but it is in a 24hr format and I want it to be in a 12 hr format with am/pm.

I tried this:

```
$('.emltdp-emltd-test').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
});
```

but its not working.

Comment: You may find your answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847109/formatting-the-date-time-with-javascript

Comment: @DwightDavidDesotelleJr. - The OP is asking for helping using a specific jQuery widget library. The post you've linked to has nothing to do with the library in the question.

Comment: [From the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414219/time-format-not-working-for-datetimepicker/29415415#comment47026219_29415415): "*Thanks #JDB I forgot to add something. :)*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, and I can verify that it *should* work if it matches what you've posted. Just make sure you don't have any spelling or capitalization mistakes in your actual code.

```js
$(function(){

  $('.emltdp-emltd-test').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />

<input class="emltdp-emltd-test" />
```

Comment: Thanks #JDB I forgot to add something. :)