# javascript subtract two times from each other

Tags: javascript

So, I try to get a difference bewteen two times (not dates) but it doesn't work at all.

This is the javascript code I'm using now:

```
function getTimeBeforeClockIn() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/get-trip-ideal-stop-time',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (ideal_stop_time){
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);
            var cur_time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            console.log(cur_time);
            console.log(ideal_stop_time);
            var stime = (new Date(new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + ideal_stop_time));
            var time_difference = cur_time - stime;
            console.log(time_difference);
            document.getElementById('ideal_time_for_stop').innerHTML = time_difference;
        }
    });

    var t = setTimeout(getTimeBeforeClockIn, 500);
}
```

The ajax call returns a string with the format `hh:mm:ss` so like `22:09:25`

So I want the difference between a `new Date();` object and a `string` (since the ajax call gets a string)

I want to get the difference between the current time and the time from the ajax call. This can be positive and negative. So if the time is negative, then it should get an output like `- 00:08:25` format: `hh:mm:ss` else it needs an output with a `+`

hope someone can help me with this?

Comment: what is `checkTime`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: Why don't you simply find the difference between `stime` and `today`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I don't think that's a real duplicate.  Perhaps techniques will overlap, but this clearly has to do with time of day.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it is not a duplicate. I have a **string** and a **time**object, I need to know the difference between those two.

Comment: I would convert to seconds and operate with that.

Comment: Well, since there's no such thing as a time object, you have a Date object, so you'll need to get the difference between two Dates. There are several answers in the question which describe how to get more granular differences than days. There are other questions regarding how to parse and format dates. Combine them together and you'll get your answer.

Comment: For parsing a time into a Date: https://stackoverflow.com/q/141348/215552; formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8847109/215552

Comment: Something like this was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/q/1787939/8068435

Answer (score 0):

You want to do:

```
var time_difference=today-stime;
```

This will give you the number of seconds between those two Date objects. Then convert those seconds into the time format that you want.