# how to get this specific datetime format in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, format

In javascript, is there a way to convert a date time to the following format:

```
// 11/3/18, 12:00 AM

Date().toString() gives me:

Sat Nov 03 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Comment: Don't read w3schools
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting the date time with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847109/formatting-the-date-time-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative to format dates, the function [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) allows you to format date according to options/flags.

*Some js engines manage the format process differently (so, this is implementation dependent), therefore be careful.  Further, you need to check for compatibility in browsers.*

```js
let today = new Date();
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour12: true, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };

console.log(today.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
```

Answer (score 0):

*tl;dr: try typing this in your browser's javascript console on the **[moment.js website](https://momentjs.com/)**:* `moment().format('MM/d/YY h:mm A')`

**Three things:**

*1. If you haven't already, check out these date docs for the API:*

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
- (Thorough backgrounder): https://www.toptal.com/software/definitive-guide-to-datetime-manipulation

*2. Without an external library*

See Ele's answer above for most elegant non-library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135859/3191929

> Ex. Extract mm/dd/yy from Date

```
const root = new Date();
let month = root.getMonth(); // 0 to 11
let day = root.getDate(); // 1 to 31
let year = root.getFullYear(); year = String(year).slice(2);
// 11/3/18, 12:00 AM mm/dd/yy, hh:mm AM/PM
const output = ``${month}/${day}/${year}``; // mm/dd/yy
```

And from there you can explore the API to get the 24 hours, then do a check for AM/PM and build the result etc etc. (see bbram's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888498/3191929 for the relevant Date APIs for time)

Here's a quick'n'dirty solution to your specific question

> Ex. Extract mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM from Date

```
function formatDate(root) {
    let month = root.getMonth(); // 0 to 11, 0 = Jan
    month += 1; // 1 to 12, 1 = Jan
    let day = root.getDate(); // 1 to 31
    let year = root.getFullYear();
    year = String(year).slice(2);

// Time transformation appropriated from bbrame
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format/8888498#8888498
function formatAMPM(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

// mm/dd/yy, hh:mm AM/PM
const output = `${month}/${day}/${year} ${formatAMPM(root)}`;
return output;
}

var rootDate = new Date();
console.log(formatDate(rootDate)); // mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM
```

*3. With an external library*

Using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) you can achieve the above with just this:

```
var root = moment(); // valid moment date
var formatted = root.format('m/d/YY h:mm A');
```

See the moment.js docs for more details: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

If momentjs specifically is a no-go, see here for other options as well: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs

Comment: Thanks Victor, I went with Ele's suggestion, but if I ever want to try out moment in the future, I'll remember this post.