# formatting jQuery date object 'Date Feb 14 2019 | 20:02'

Tags: jquery, date

```
var dt = new Date();
var mmddyyyy = dt.getMonth() + ":" +  dt.getDay() + ":" + dt.getYear();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();

$('#elem').html(mmddyyyy  + time);
```

I'm trying the above in order to simply format ''**Date Feb 14 2019 | 20:02**'

But sadly it is outputting like:

**1:5:11916:4**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting the date time with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847109/formatting-the-date-time-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several problems here. Firstly `getMonth()` returns the zero-based index of the month of the date. To turn that in to a short name string of the month you can define your own array which you can access by index based on that value.

You're then using `getDay()` which returns the current day of the week. I presume you want `getDate()` instead which gives you the current day of the month. Then you'll need `getFullYear()` to get a four-digit year value, instead of `getYear()`.

Finally, with the times you will need to pad the leading zeros on the hours and minutes before concatenating them to the final output string.

With all that said, try this:

```js
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

var dt = new Date();
var mmddyyyy = months[dt.getMonth()] + ' ' +  dt.getDate() + ' ' + dt.getFullYear();

var time = ('00' + dt.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('00' + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

$('#elem').html(mmddyyyy + ' | ' + time);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem"></div>
```

If you require any further modifications to this I'd suggest reading the [Date() object reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). It's covers all methods available for date formatting.