# How to convert JSON time stamp in javascript to date and time?

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, timestamp

I am getting Time stamp as "2020-03-02T05:50:31.000Z"

How to convert this to Normal Readable Format with Date and Time Zone

Comment: What is `Normal Readable Format` to you? For me, you already have it. Also, what have you tried? Plenty of questions already deal with date/time formatting in JavaScript.

Comment: I mean it as to normal time and date format

Comment: use new Date("2020-03-02T05:50:31.000Z"), and then use different methods to get the date in format you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting the date time with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847109/formatting-the-date-time-with-javascript)

Comment: That already follows normal [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) what format do you want it on?

Comment: Please provide description or example of Normal Readable Format. search on stackoverflow will give you plenty of answers. *date format in js site:stackoverflow.com*

Answer (score 3):

```js
const parsedDate = new Date("2020-03-02T05:50:31.000Z");
console.log(parsedDate.toGMTString())
//"Mon, 02 Mar 2020 05:50:31 GMT"
console.log(parsedDate.toLocaleString())
//"3/2/2020, 11:20:31 AM"
console.log(parsedDate.toDateString(), parsedDate.toTimeString())
//Mon Mar 02 2020 11:20:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: why the intermediate Date.parse?

Answer (score 2):

In java-script above date format can be parsed by using Date.

Eg:

```
var date = new Date('2020-03-02T05:50:31.000Z');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean readable format but you can use following methods:

```
new Date('2020-03-02T05:50:31.000Z').toLocaleString();
// outputs date according to user locale settings
```

Or you can use `getYear`, `getMonth`, `getDay` methods to get them and format date as you want

Comment: why the intermediate Date.parse?

Comment: You likely mean *getDate*, which gets the day of the month, not *getDay* (which gets the day of the week),

Answer (score -1):

You can use moment.js for date time format and conversion.
Pass your date timestamp as below:

```
moment.parseZone("2020-03-02T05:50:31.000Z").format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss z Z")
```

Modify format as you need ref mentioned [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Use in your code as mentioned [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/)