# How to get the minimum and maximum date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do I get the smallest and biggest date. I see that the smallest number can be got like this:

```
Number.MIN_VALUE
```

Date does not have this. Is there a way to find the smallest and biggest date

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Date does not have this

Actually, it does, but only indirectly. According to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1), a `Date` object's milliseconds-since-the-Epoch value can only be in the range -8640000000000000 to 8640000000000000.

So the minimum date is `new Date(-8640000000000000)` (Tue, 20 Apr -271821 00:00:00 GMT), and the maximum date is `new Date(8640000000000000)` (Sat, 13 Sep 275760 00:00:00 GMT).

If you wanted, you could put those on the `Date` function as properties:

```
Date.MIN_VALUE = new Date(-8640000000000000);
Date.MAX_VALUE = new Date(8640000000000000);
```

...but since `Date` instances are mutable, I probably wouldn't, because it's too easy to accidentally modify one of them. An alternative would be to do this:

```
Object.defineProperties(Date, {
    MIN_VALUE: {
      value: -8640000000000000 // A number, not a date
    },
    MAX_VALUE: {
      value: 8640000000000000
    }
});
```

That defines properties on `Date` that cannot be changed that have the min/max numeric value for dates. (On a JavaScript engine that has ES5 support.)

Comment: OMG, you must have an upside-down brain to think of this @T.J. Crowder! There is only 1 issue with your answer, what if year 275760 has come, what would happen? :P Great answer!

Comment: @evilReiko: That's an issue with the JavaScript Date object, not my answer. **;-)**

Comment: @evilReiko hopefully an alternative to javascript is found by then.  If not, then hopefully we have gone extinct ;)