# min and max date not working on formik/material-ui/datepicker component

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, formik

This is driving me crazy.  I can't get min and max date to work at all.  Here's my code:

```html
          <DatePickerField
            name={dob.name}
            label={dob.label}
            format="MM/DD/YYYY"
            minDate={new Date('12/31/1920')}
            maxDate={new Date()}
            fullWidth
            onChange={(event, newdate) => { currentAge = calculateAge(newdate, currentAge); }}
          />
```

No matter what date I use, like 1/1/1800, it shows up in the input field for the date picker and the age shows  up as 220 years old (as an example).  Same goes if I pick a date in the future.  Age shows up as -whatever.  The calucateAge function is working fine, but DatePickerField is accepting ANY date.

Why is it not forcing a min and max date?

EDITED TO ADD BELOW:

This is the DatePickerField I am using that I adapted from Formik:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useField } from 'formik';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from '@material-ui/pickers';

const DatePickerField = props => {
  const [field, meta, helper] = useField(props);
  const { touched, error } = meta;
  const { setValue } = helper;
  const isError = touched && error && true;
  const { value } = field;
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
  //console.log("datepickerfield" + JSON.stringify(field) + "end of datepickerfield");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
      const date = new Date(value);
      setSelectedDate(date);
    }
  }, [value]);

  function _onChange(date) {
    if (date) {
      setSelectedDate(date);
      try {
        const ISODateString = date.toISOString();
        setValue(ISODateString);
      } catch (error) {
        setValue(date);
      }
    } else {
      setValue(date);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          {...field}
          {...props}
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={_onChange}
          error={isError}
          invalidDateMessage={isError && error}
          helperText={isError && error}
          disableToolbar
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change date',
          }}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default DatePickerField;
```

At this point I don't know if the problem lies in the call or the DatePickerField.jsx file itself.

Any help would be truly appreciated!

Comment: a link for you to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093130/how-to-get-the-minimum-and-maximum-date

Answer (score 0):

You need to use strings and not a date

```html
    <DatePickerField
        name={dob.name}
        label={dob.label}
        format="MM/DD/YYYY"
        minDate={new Date('12/31/1920').toString()}
        maxDate={new Date().toString()}
        fullWidth
        onChange={(event, newdate) => { currentAge = calculateAge(newdate, currentAge); }}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I thought this might work, but I'd already tried it and it made no difference. Date still remained the same.  So that doesn't fix it.