# Javascript Date MAX_VALUE

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, date, max

In JavaScript, what is the maximum value for the year in a Date?

How can I find this out in code?

I have tried the following:

```
new Date().getFullYear().MAX_VALUE;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526504/minimum-and-maximum-date)

Comment: How about the largest Date, not the smallest?

Comment: in answer above describes the situation about largest date too

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per specs here: https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range : The actual range of times is 8,640,000,000,000,000 milliseconds to either side of 01 January, 1970 UTC. So, the maximum valid year you will get is 275760 (`new Date(8640000000000000).getFullYear()`). And to get the minimum valid year, `new Date(-8640000000000000).getFullYear()` or 271821 B.C.E.

Comment: So ... ... I should have a `try... catch` on dates so that my code is ready for the September 12, 275760 bug. Got it.

Comment: @YanickRochon The call to `Date().getFullYear()` shouldn't throw an error but instead return `NaN`. So it depends on how your code handles that.