# I want to set date as infinite in form of timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to set the date as an infinite date in form of timestamp?
There are people saying we can use "0" and some are saying set big value like this `60*60*24*100`. And I do not want to do this. Is there any suitable way of handling this?

Answer (score 22):

`0` and `60*60*24*100` are bad choices because they are *small* values (in the first few hours of 1st January 1970).

If you need to deal with the timestamps as a number only, use `Infinity`. It has the properties I assume you need:

```
Infinity > Date.now()
// true

Infinity > 60*60*24*100
// true

Infinity > Number.MAX_VALUE
// true
```

However, it won't work if you need to convert to `Date`:

```
new Date(Infinity)
// Invalid Date
```

If you also need to construct a `Date` for your timestamp, the largest possible timestamp is `8640000000000000` - see [Minimum and maximum date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526504/minimum-and-maximum-date).

```
var MAX_TIMESTAMP = 8640000000000000;

new Date(MAX_TIMESTAMP)
// Sat Sep 13 275760 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

new Date(MAX_TIMESTAMP + 1)
// Invalid Date
```