# How to set minimum and maximum date of asp:textbox textmode=date ??? using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp:textbox , how can i set its minimum date to today using javascript:

With C# I am doing it like this and it works fine..but I have to do it using Js/Jquery

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today.Date;
            String today = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            tourStartDate.Attributes["min"] =today;
<asp:TextBox Width="95%" ID="tourStartDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date" onchange="SetDate()"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimum and maximum date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526504/minimum-and-maximum-date)

Comment: Can you show the SetDate() method ?

Comment: function SetDate() {

    if (document.getElementById('<%=tourEndDate.ClientID%>').value <= document.getElementById('<%=tourStartDate.ClientID%>').value) {
            $('#<%=tourEndDate.ClientID %>').val(document.getElementById('<%=tourStartDate.ClientID%>').value);
        }

Comment: @SyedMuhammadYasir Please add the content of your comment to your question. After that delete your comment.

Answer (score 3):

On Code Behind C#:

```
tourStartDate.Attributes["max"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

VB.net:

```
tourStartDate.Attributes("max") = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the `ClientIdMode = static` in the server control to get the static Id.

```
<asp:TextBox Width="95%" ID="tourStartDate" ClientIdMode = "static" runat="server" TextMode="Date" onchange="SetDate()"></asp:TextBox>
```

Jquery: Set today in attribute.

```
$("#tourStartDate").attr("min", (new Date()));
```

**EDIT:**

Can you try `<input type="date" min="2015-07-01" max="2015-10-20">`

JQuery:

```
  $("#tourStartDate").attr("min", (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0,10));
```

Make sure your doc type is html ( for HTML 5 controls)

**EDIT2 :**

JavaScript :

```
 document.getElementById('tourStartDate').setAttribute('min', (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0,10));
```

Comment: I want to set current date as minimum date

Comment: Check this line
$("#tourStartDate").attr("min", (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0,10));

Comment: how can this be done by using min max attribute via javascript

Comment: @SyedMuhammadYasir check the updated answer for setting attribute value by javascript

Answer (score 0):

**My design code is :**

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" MaxLength="30" CssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Javascript code and jquery code**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    maxDate: new Date()
  });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).