# What is the earliest date an html date input can go?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, input

In C# you can do [DateTime.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but is there any method for this in JavaScript or HTML?

I am aware of `Date(-number)` in JavaScript, but the constants for `number` that I can find are all too big, and there doesn't seem to be a max/min value

Comment: Scrap that, apparently I hadn't found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526504/minimum-and-maximum-date

Comment: While that answer might suit javascript (i.e. ECMAScript), HTML pages aren't limited to javascript for the scripting language. The [*HTML specification*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#date-state-(type=date)) has no such limit.

Comment: It might have no limit, but the date input selector gets real buggy in the year 275760

Comment: The implementation notes in HTML5 say: "*For the input of dates before the introduction of the Gregorian calendar, authors are encouraged to not use the Date and Time state … as user agents are not required to support converting dates and times from earlier periods to the Gregorian calendar…*" so that seems to provide a "soft" limit. The [*Gregorian calendar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) was introduced at different times in different places, but maybe 1582 is a suitable lower limit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, this should be Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

Hope this helps!

Thanks
Shyam

Comment: It's actually `Tue Apr 20 -271821 12:00:00`

Comment: That's the epoch, not the earliest date.

Comment: Yes you are correct, upon trying to set the `input value="-271821-04-20"` it wouldn't accept it, marking this as the answer