# C# DateTime.MaxValue equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Is there any way to get the same value of date time in javascript that `c#` `DateTime.MaxValue` returns?

Comment: This can possibly help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526504/minimum-and-maximum-date

Answer (score 4):

The above edge case as mentioned by James Thorpe can be avoided by using:

```
    public dateTimeMax = new Date(9999, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999);
```

This is because the month is zero-indexed, and the highest value it can take for milliseconds is 999.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes. The max date in .NET is `23:59:59.9999999 UTC, December 31, 9999`. So this would be the equivalent Javascript:

```
var d = new Date(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 9999999);
```

There is no `Date.MaxValue` in Javascript, so you have to make it your own.

Comment: Just replace 12 with 11
var d = new Date(9999, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59, 9999999);