# How does JavaScript Date.getTime() (milliseconds) map to a 64-bit float?

Tags: javascript, qt, date, double, gettime

I am confused about JavaScript's `Date` object and its `getTime()` method.
From:
[Minimum and maximum date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526504/minimum-and-maximum-date)

It says that the actual max and min. number of milliseconds (ms) representable by a JS `Date` object is (-/+)8.640.000.000.000.000 ms since 01 January, 1970 UTC.

However, 8.640.000.000.000.000 requires 53 bits.

On the other, hand, all JS numbers are 64-bit floats with only 52 fractional bits (excluding the sign bit).

How can JS therefore store the result of `Date.getTime()` when `Date` is either the max or the min date value? It must use one of the exponent bits to do this, right?

Does that also mean that converting a JS `Date` (via its number of ms) to int64 (e.g. for use in Qt) is not strictly possible?

Comment: [52 fractional bits is the same as 53 significant bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543600/5267751). "Since we are using binary (only 0 and 1), one bit in the mantissa is implicitly 1 (both float and double use this trick) when the number is non-zero."

Comment: Planning more than 100k years ahead?

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about the normalization which makes the msb always 1 (for non-zero numbers) and can therefore be made implicit, effectively giving an extra bit...

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript represents numbers using IEEE-754 double-precision (64 bit) format. it  gives you 53 bits precision. JS internally stores as 64-bit floating point numbers and JavaScript dates are internally stored as milliseconds since epoch.You can use **[getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)** method of JavaScript . I will return epoch value . This epoch value can be used in Qt as epoch value or create date from this epoch value  using

[fromMSecsSinceEpoch(qint64 msecs)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromMSecsSinceEpoch)