# How to handle large dates with momentjs?

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs

I am trying to find a difference in months between two moment objects. I did as follows:

```
const current = moment()
const future = moment().add('324523546345634563456345','months')
const diff = future.diff(current, 'months')
```

The `diff` comes out as 0. Why is that? Is there a different way to handle large numbers like `324523546345634563456345`?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: your input exceeds the limitations of JavaScript's built-in integer and Date types. To do calculations with such large numbers, use type [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). (Most date libraries like MomentJS won't support `BigInt`, one of the reasons being regular integers provide a reasonable range of dates.)

---

The largest integer that can be represented by JavaScript built-in numbers is [9,007,199,254,740,991](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/117030). Floating point numbers go much higher, but probably don't make sense for this type of use case (there would be too many floating point gaps).

Your input: 324,523,546,345,634,563,456,345 is many orders of magnitude greater than what JavaScript built-in integers support. This is even before considering the additional orders of magnitude after converting months to milliseconds.

Frankly, I'm surprised the result was 0 and not `NaN`.

Furthermore, I believe MomentJS internally uses the built-in JavaScript Date type. The max date is about the [year 275,760](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526569/117030). Your input would require support for a year way, way past this year. In fact, your input is greater than [the age of the universe](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=age%20of%20universe%20in%20months).

If you really need to make such a calculation, you could use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)s. You'll probably have to do the calculations manually because I don't think any time-related library will support such large dates.

Comment: I think moment's duration can handle the large numbers. Not sure why the discrepancy exists.