# Wrong date display in Highcharts graph

Tags: datetime, highcharts, label, axis

I have a graph which portrays data 802.000 years back in time. However, I don't succeed in making Highcharts understand the datetime setting... I tried it with different year formatting, such as "-800000" or "Date.UTC(-800000,01,01)", but in vain.

The xaxis doesn't show the correct years...
[image]

The xaxis setting is just

```
type:"datetime"
```

The data look like this:

```
Date.UTC(1975,01,01),,329.4,,331.08,3.336.116.667,,,,,
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/cnoqgexh/7/).

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this thread about minimum and maximum date: [Minimum and maximum date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526504/minimum-and-maximum-date)

Because that is a general date issue, I recommend you to use a `category` axis type:

```
xAxis: {
    type: "category",
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vwnuqmch/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't know the thing with the minimum @ "01 January, 1970 UTC". However, with »category« the distance between the data points, which are not equal, they are always rendered the same. With »datetime«, it respects the differences. Played a bit around, and seems to work now, with no »type« defined and a Javascript function to convert to DecimalDate used. [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/cnoqgexh/10/).

Comment: Hi @luftikus143, The default type is `linear`, so yes - that is also a good solution.