# Bug in JavaScript date 1 Jan 0099

Tags: javascript

On 1 jan 0099  there was  `Thrusday`  but it return.  `Friday`

```
days = new Date(" January 1 ,0099")
day = days.getDay()
alert(day);
```

RESULT
`5`

But it should return `4`

Comment: _"year repeat after every 400 years"_ - What do you mean by that?

Comment: January 1, 1999 was a Friday, so the result should be 5.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, same calendar doesn't repeat with 400 years period.

Comment: @Ivar That's not correct, `new Date(1900, 0, 1)` does just fine.

Comment: @deceze Interesting. Given that "_Date objects contain a Number that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC_", I expected dates should be after that. But [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526504/minimum-and-maximum-date) that number can be negative and we can go back to the year -271821.

Comment: @Ivar Since Date objects are not rarely used for birthdays, it would be very unreasonable for them to not at least support the past 100 years or so.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, it appears Javascript won't construct a Date in the year 99:

> `year`
>   Integer value representing the year.
>
> Values from 0 to 99 map to the years 1900 to 1999. All other values are the actual year.
>
> <sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Syntax</sub>

You can try with different formats, `99` always appears to map to `1999`. Likely this was implemented as a workaround and/or “convenience” for Y2K dates, perhaps even inherited from Java.

I'm not sure if there's a better workaround, but this works:

```
let d = new Date(100, 0, 1);
d.setFullYear(99);
```