# How to reload data in Google Charts Calendar while keeping selected cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, calendar, google-visualization

I use jQuery and I use the following JS function to load and reload / redraw the Google Chart Calendar.

It works, however, it also removes the border from the selected item. I want to reload the calendar data, while keeping the currently selected item selected.

[image]

Any ideas?

```
function refreshCalendar( rows)
{
    //if( calendar != 0 )
    {
        calendar = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'))

        google.visualization.events.addListener(calendar, 'select', calendarSelectHandler);

        calendarData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        calendarData.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
        calendarData.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Logs' });
        calendarData.addRows( rows );

        calendarOptions = {
            title: "Logs",
            height: 175,
            colorAxis: {minValue: 0,  colors: ['#FFFFFF', '#FF0000']},
            calendar: {
              focusedCellColor: {
                background: '#00FF00',
                stroke: '#004400',
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWidth: 2,
              },
              cellColor: {
                stroke: '#76a7fa',
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWidth: 1,
              }
            }
        };

        calendar.draw(calendarData, calendarOptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would use `chart.getSelection` and `chart.setSelection`.

Get selection on `'select'` event
Set selection on `'ready'` event

`getSelection` works fine, but `setSelection` doesn't work with the Calendar chart.
No error is thrown, but nothing is selected.
I tried versions `'41'` thru `'current'`...

To demonstrate, the following example uses both a Calendar chart and a Column chart.
Make a selection on both charts, then click "Redraw Chart".
The selection for the Column chart remains but not on the Calendar.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['calendar', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var selectionCal;
  var selectionCol;

  var calendar = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'))
  google.visualization.events.addListener(calendar, 'select', function () {
    selectionCal = calendar.getSelection();
  });
  google.visualization.events.addListener(calendar, 'ready', function () {
    if (selectionCal) {
      calendar.setSelection(selectionCal);
    }
  });

  var column = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('column'))
  google.visualization.events.addListener(column, 'select', function () {
    selectionCol = column.getSelection();
  });
  google.visualization.events.addListener(column, 'ready', function () {
    if (selectionCol) {
      column.setSelection(selectionCol);
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('test_button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    calendar.draw(calendarData, calendarOptions);
    column.draw(calendarData, {});
  }, false);

  var calendarData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  calendarData.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
  calendarData.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Logs' });
  calendarData.addRows([
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 15), 38024 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 16), 38108 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 17), 38229 ],
  ]);

  var calendarOptions = {
      title: "Logs",
      height: 175,
      colorAxis: {minValue: 0,  colors: ['#FFFFFF', '#FF0000']},
      calendar: {
        focusedCellColor: {
          background: '#00FF00',
          stroke: '#004400',
          strokeOpacity: 1,
          strokeWidth: 2,
        },
        cellColor: {
          stroke: '#76a7fa',
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWidth: 1,
        }
      }
  };

  calendar.draw(calendarData, calendarOptions);
  column.draw(calendarData, {});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
<div id="column"></div>
<input type="button" id="test_button" value="Redraw Chart" />
```

Comment: So you're proving that it is not possible for calendars?

Comment: that is correct, only other way would be to modify the SVG once the chart's ready event has fired / try to place your own marker

Comment: I've also ran into this problem when trying to clear the selected cell with chart.setSelection(); [doesn't work]

Answer (score 0):

I can also confirm that the `setSelection()` method doesn't change anything on the UI for the calendar chart.

So I looked up what happens after selecting a day in the chart with the mouse. Then I implemented a simple DOM manipulation logic which does the same. You can use that logic as a replacement of the `setSelection()` use case. (It is just a quick prototype, but I hope it helps you, too).

For a litte demo I adjusted @WhiteHat [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36093217/810944) / the selected day survives now the refresh action (doesn't work with charts which needs to display more than one year!):

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['calendar', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var selectionCal;
  var selectionDate;
  var selectionCol;

  var calendar = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'))
  google.visualization.events.addListener(calendar, 'select', function () {
    selectionCal = calendar.getSelection();
    selectionDate = new Date(selectionCal[0].date);
  });
  google.visualization.events.addListener(calendar, 'ready', function () {
    if (selectionDate) {
      // google calendar setSelection BUG :/
      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/36093217/810944
      // do it manually
      var doy = selectionDate.getDOY();
      markDayInChart(doy);
    }
  });

  var column = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('column'))
  google.visualization.events.addListener(column, 'select', function () {
    selectionCol = column.getSelection();
  });
  google.visualization.events.addListener(column, 'ready', function () {
    if (selectionCol) {
      column.setSelection(selectionCol);
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('test_button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    calendar.draw(calendarData, calendarOptions);
    column.draw(calendarData, {});
  }, false);

  var calendarData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  calendarData.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
  calendarData.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Logs' });
  calendarData.addRows([
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 15), 38024 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 16), 38108 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 17), 38229 ],
  ]);

  var calendarOptions = {
      title: "Logs",
      height: 175,
      colorAxis: {minValue: 0,  colors: ['#FFFFFF', '#FF0000']},
      calendar: {
        focusedCellColor: {
          background: '#00FF00',
          stroke: '#004400',
          strokeOpacity: 1,
          strokeWidth: 2,
        },
        cellColor: {
          stroke: '#76a7fa',
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWidth: 1,
        }
      }
  };

  calendar.draw(calendarData, calendarOptions);
  column.draw(calendarData, {});
}

function markDayInChart(dayOfYear) {
    // clones the logic for clicking / selecting a day via mouse
    // keep in mind to clean up the adjusted and added `rect`-elements if you do not use full page reloads!
    // doesn't work with charts which needs to display more than one year!
    var days_all_svg_group = $('#calendar svg').children('g')[1];
    var days_marked_svg_group = $('#calendar svg').children('g')[4];
    var day_svg_rect = $('rect:nth-of-type('+dayOfYear+')',$(days_all_svg_group));

    // hide the original rect
    $(day_svg_rect).css('display: none;');

    // add a cloned rect with a different stroke
    var day_marked_svg_rect = $(day_svg_rect).clone();
    $(day_marked_svg_rect).attr({stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 2});
    $(day_marked_svg_rect).attr('stroke-opacity', null);
    $(days_marked_svg_group).append(day_marked_svg_rect);
  }

  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26426761/810944
  Date.prototype.isLeapYear = function() {
    var year = this.getFullYear();
    if((year & 3) != 0) return false;
    return ((year % 100) != 0 || (year % 400) == 0);
  };

  // Get Day of Year
  Date.prototype.getDOY = function() {
      var dayCount = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334];
      var mn = this.getMonth();
      var dn = this.getDate();
      var dayOfYear = dayCount[mn] + dn;
      if(mn > 1 && this.isLeapYear()) dayOfYear++;
      return dayOfYear;
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
<div id="column"></div>
<input type="button" id="test_button" value="Redraw Chart" />
```