# Get full date from day of the year

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm using js and jquery. I've been looking on the page and I found this:
[Javascript calculate the day of the year (1 - 366)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619879/javascript-calculate-the-day-of-the-year-1-366) 
I'm trying to do the oposite.

For example:

`208` would be `today (2016/07/26)`

Any idea how could i do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortest way:

```
new Date(2016, 0, 208)
```

will return `Date 2016-07-26`

Comment: Easier than I expected. Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
function dateFromDay(year, day){
  var date = new Date(year, 0); // initialize a date in `year-01-01`
  return new Date(date.setDate(day)); // add the number of days
}

dateFromDay(2016, 208);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function dayNumToDate(numDays) {
  var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  var initDate = new Date("JANUARY, 1," +  thisYear);
  var millis = numDays * 24 * 60 *60 * 10000; 
  var newDate = new Date(millis + initDate.getTime());
  return newDate;
}
var date = dayNumToDate(208);
alert(date.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

//To initialize date function

```
var now = new Date();
```

// the number of day to convert in Date

```
var curr_day_number = 208;
```

//Calculate total time of a single day

```
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

//Calculate total time all days so

```
var total_number_of_time_of_day = curr_day_number * oneDay;
```

//calcuclate start day of the year

```
var start_date_of_year = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
```

//calculate start date of year time stamp

```
var start_date_of_year_timestamp = new Date(start_date_of_year).getTime();
```

//calulate total time stamp start of the year with total days of the year

```
var calculated_timestamp = start_date_of_year_timestamp + total_number_of_time_of_day;
```

// convert time stamp into Date using Date function

```
var calculated_date = new Date(calculated_timestamp);

document.write(calculated_date);
```

This will help you out in detail.

Comment: There is solution with only one line. It complies with the specification, is concise and easily readable. So why would anyone want to use a solution that spans several lines, makes potentially error-prone calculations, and is hard to read and understand?