# Spreadsheet jump to current date issue

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Hello dear community,

I am unfortunately not able to figure out where's the issue in @Serge insas AppScript to jump to Today's cell in my own spreadsheet.

Fixed potential issue with different timezones date format, however, the script jumps to the last cell as: `sh.getRange(5,sh.getLastColumn()).activate();` indicates, but not to Today's cell.

Important to mention that my Spreadsheet is constructed horizontal, [here is the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6nYBAqB1GWoMkIOwlykhiuMpaXdWHTo7UhgZdq6hT8/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is my version:

```
function JumpToToday() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    sh.getRange(5,sh.getLastColumn()).activate();
  var data = sh.getDataRange("E5:NE5").getValues();
  var offsetToSS = new Date('22/02/2022').setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)-offsetToSS)/86400000,10)+1;
  for(var n=0;n<data[0].length;n++){
    var date = data[0][n];
    Logger.log("date = "+data[0][n]+" =? "+today);
    if(date==today){break};
  }
  n++;
  sh.getRange(1,n).activate();
}
```

Can the issue be due to the script going first to last column and then starts counting from n=0?

Comment: I think your problem is you are performing math on a Date object.  Once you have a date object such as `offsetToSS` use `offsetToSS.valueOf()`.  Same for other dates you are working with

Comment: This was my thought too, but according to @Serge insas approach this is the ONLY way to subtract the Offset value from `today()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to the current date in your sheet.

1. You have to count the number of days from January 1 up to this day.
2. Use the number of days in the `col` parameter of `Sheet.getRange(row, col, numRows, numCol)` + the number of column used before the January 1 cell.

Here I created a code that will activate the cell with the current date with the help of user2501097's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40975730):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var snoopiSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Snoopi");
  var range = snoopiSheet.getRange(5, getCurrentDayofYear() + 5, 1,1);
  range.activate();
}


function getCurrentDayofYear(){
  var date = new Date();
  return (Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()) - Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** I used Snoopi sheet in the example above, I added + 5 in the 2nd parameter of `getRange()` because the start of the count is in the 5th column or January 1. Also, when using multiple Sheets, make sure to use `ss.getSheetByName(name)` this is to prevent script from applying the code to different sheets which might happen if you use `getActiveSheet()`

### References:

- [Spreadsheet.getSheetbyName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Thank you, @Nikko J. for the deep dive into this DATE format questions, I find it rather weird that simple Spreadsheet formulas can produce quick & accurate date calculations but with AppScripts it makes thing lot more complicated.

Comment: However, I've tried various ways to implement this script into my Spreadsheet and had no success - BTW my timezone is (UTC +1).

Comment: EDIT: I got the script running perfect on "RUN", just had to adjust the triggers - works like a charm, thank you very much again Nikko!

Answer (score 1):

Well I learned something new today.  Date.valueOf() and Date.setHours(0,0,0,0) return the same, the value of date in milliseconds.  But your date is invalid.

new Date("22/02/2022") returns Invalid date.

```
function dummy() {
  try {
    var offsetToSS = new Date('02/22/2022').valueOf();
    console.log(offsetToSS);
    var offsetToSS = new Date('02/22/2022').setHours(0,0,0,0);
    console.log(offsetToSS);
    var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)-offsetToSS)/86400000,10)+1;
    console.log(today);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

8:14:09 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:14:09 AM  Info    1645506000000
8:14:09 AM  Info    1645506000000
8:14:09 AM  Info    1
8:14:09 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Interesting approach, where can I see the additional values logs?

Comment: There is an error in your original post `new Date("22/2/2022")` gives me invalid date error.

Comment: Yeah but when I ran the script there were no errors, how can I see them to know for future implication?

Comment: As I'm developing and debugging a script that can be run from the script editor I wrap my code in a `try { } catch(err) { }` as I've show above.  That was how my dummy function alerted me to the "22/02/2022" error.  If you are running from the menu you can use `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);` in the catch block.