# appendChild in javascript repeats the value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing my date dropdown picker. I have 3 dropdowns for selecting a year, month and day. I used javascript for that. The program runned when I choose a year then javascript will append months[1'2,3,4,5, and so on] in my month dropdown. As well as when I choose a month for example 2-->February, it will append 28 days only in my day dropdown. It works well but the problem is everytime I change to a new year, the value of my month dropdown is repeated as well as in days.

example:

```
     year dropdown --- I choose 1970
     month dropdown ----- [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
     dates dropdown ----[1-31]
```

when I choose another year:

```
     year dropdown --- I choose 1972
     month dropdown ----- [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
     dates dropdown ----[1-31]
```

As you can see the value in my month dropdown repeat only.

my codes is below:

```js
 
        function daysInMonth(m, y){
        return m===2?y&3||!(y%25)&&y&15?28:29:30+(m+(m>>3)&1);
     }
        
        var monthArray = [];
        var dateArray = []; 
        function onYearChange() {
         $(this).parent().remove();
         var year = document.getElementById("yeardialog").value
               if (document.getElementById("yeardialog").value != "0"){
                  for(var i = 1 ; i<=12; i++){
                      monthArray.push(i);
                      dateArray.push(daysInMonth(i, year));
                }

              var select = document.getElementById("monthdialog");
         for(var i = 0; i < monthArray.length; i++) {
            var monthOptions = monthArray[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
             el.textContent = monthOptions;
             el.value = monthOptions;
          select.appendChild(el);
        }
            }         
   }

function onMonthChange(){


   var dates =[]; 
   var month = document.getElementById("monthdialog").value;
   var endDay = dateArray[month-1];

   for(var date = 1; date<=endDay; date++){
    dates.push(date);
   }

          var select = document.getElementById("datedialog");
     for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        var dateOptions = dates[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
         el.textContent = dateOptions;
         el.value = dateOptions;
          select.appendChild(el);
     }
  }
```

```html
  <select id="yeardialog" name="yeardialog" onchange="onYearChange()">
   <option value=""> -- </option>
      {for $i = 1970; $i <= 2015; $i++ }
       <option value={$i} >{$i}</option>
      {/for}
    </select>

    <select id="monthdialog" onchange="onMonthChange()">
      <option></option>
 </select>

  <select id="datedialog">
      <option></option>
  </select>

       <div id="message">
          
  </div>
```

Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This code doesn't run for me. What template system are you using? I'm not sure if it's supported by stackoverflow, maybe you can put it on jsfiddle?

Comment: I think your problem is probably solved by either only ever adding the months once or clearing the select out before adding them so you don't repeatedly add them.

Comment: I used code igniter for that. I think the reason is that is why not working because I used php in yeardialog.

Comment: How to clear the select before appending them again. ?

Comment: you can just use one line like this before appending child like this document.getElementById("monthdialog").innerHTML = "";

Comment: [explanation of my `daysInMonth` algo here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27810801/588079).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the month select box each time user changes year:

```
var select = document.getElementById("monthdialog");
select.innerHTML = "";     // <= Clear options like this and then add optons
 for(var i = 0; i < monthArray.length; i++) {
  var monthOptions = monthArray[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = monthOptions;
  el.value = monthOptions;
  select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Snippet:

```js
function onYearChange() {
  var select = document.getElementById('monthdialog');
  select.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = i;
    el.value = i;
    select.appendChild(el);
  }

}
```

```html
<select id="yeardialog" name="yeardialog" onchange="onYearChange()">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="1990">1990</option>
  <option value="1991">1991</option>
  <option value="1992">1992</option>

</select>
<select id="monthdialog" onchange="onMonthChange()">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Okay. I will just implement that codes to mine. Thank u very much.