# Dependent date selectors using html selects and dates to make sense

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, usability

I Am trying to build a custom START and END date selector, but unfortunatelly because of the design I won't be able to use the jquery UI Datepicker, so I am stucked with the old fashionate of splitting the dates in 3 `<select>`s

In order to keep this feature usable, we find this -at least- complicated parts:

- Let days make sense with each month (Dont want 31 of feb selectable , ..)
- Set next thay from START to the END selector

So I thought better to delegate the date calculation to the javascript Date() object so at least I can abstrat that part.

I am almost there,

But some how the Date() object tell the right date, but both selectors show each set of Days for the previous one (For example, top 28 days happen in March instead of FEB)

```
    $(function(){

months = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','ago','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
        /* Cachear selects */
        var $ld = $('select[name=llegada-dia]');
        var $lm = $('select[name=llegada-mes]');
        var $ly = $('select[name=llegada-ano]');
        var $sd = $('select[name=salida-dia]');
        var $sm = $('select[name=salida-mes]');
        var $sy = $('select[name=salida-ano]');
        var manyDays = function( month, year ){
            var fecha = new Date(year, (month) , 0);
            return fecha.getDate();
        }
        var paintCals = function( day, month , year ){
            if(day == '') day = 1;
            if(month == '') month = 0;
            if(year == '' ) year = 2013;
            //month = month -1;
            var fecha = new Date( year, month , day );          
            var dia = fecha.getDate();
            var mes = fecha.getMonth();
            var anyo = fecha.getFullYear();
            var dias_mes = manyDays( mes,anyo );
            /* Generate next date = fecha + 1 */
            var next_fecha = fecha;

            next_fecha.setDate(next_fecha.getDate() + 1); 
            next_fecha.setMonth(fecha.getMonth() + (dia == dias_mes ? 1 : 0)   ); 
            next_fecha.setFullYear(fecha.getFullYear() + (mes == 12 ? 1 : 0)  ); 

            var next_dia = next_fecha.getDate();
            var next_mes = next_fecha.getMonth();
            var next_anyo = next_fecha.getFullYear();
            var next_dias_mes = manyDays( next_mes, next_anyo ) ;
            $ld.empty();
            for(var tmpdia = 1; tmpdia <= dias_mes; tmpdia++){
                var doption = $('<option>').attr( 'value',tmpdia )
                                           .text( tmpdia );
                if(dia == tmpdia && dia != ''){
                    doption.attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
                $ld.append(doption);
            }
            /* Actualizar dias salida */
            $sd.empty();
            for(var tmpdia = next_dia; tmpdia <= next_dias_mes; tmpdia++){
                var doption = $('<option>').attr( 'value' , tmpdia )
                                           .text(tmpdia);
                if(next_dia == tmpdia && next_dia != ''){
                    doption.attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
                $sd.append(doption);
            }
            /* Actualizar meses salida */
            $sm.empty();
            for(var tmpmes = next_mes ; tmpmes < 12; tmpmes++){
                var doption = $('<option>').attr('value',tmpmes)
                                           .text(months[tmpmes]);
                if(dia == tmpdia && dia != ''){
                    doption.attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
                $sm.append(doption);
            }
            /* Actualizar anyos salida */
            $sy.empty();
            for(var tmpanyo = next_anyo; tmpanyo <= 2020; tmpanyo++){
                var doption = $('<option>').attr('value',tmpanyo)
                                           .text(tmpanyo);
                if(next_anyo == tmpanyo && next_anyo != ''){
                    doption.attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
                $sy.append(doption);
            }
        } 
        $('.arrival select').on('change',function(){
            var ldia = $ld.val();
            var lmes = $lm.val();
            var lano = $ly.val();
            var ldias = paintCals(ldia,lmes,lano);
        });
    })
```

And here it can be fiddled:

http://jsfiddle.net/96qyH/8/

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: I know the problem is that I'm starting/getting with 1 instead of 0 or the other way somewhere in the code.. Any good eyes around? I'm not able to see it..

Comment: If the jquery UI Datepicker is what you would like why don't you tweak it to your needs?

Comment: I will start working on a project for this thing, I will post it in some time! :) You can have the code for that..wait..

Comment: You may have the bounty for 5 days ^^ @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan

Comment: @Jonathan I tried a little bit at first, but I just couldn't see how can it help :?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Would really appreciate if you check out the answers and leave some comments if it worked for you. I have posted mine as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/19507870/297641

Comment: I have done it in all except the ones created today, I will asap ;) @Vega

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I am glad you did. Giving a fair chance might let you find a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Refactored some code to remove extra logic

I have used three utility function to update the start and end date drop down.

1. `daysInMonth` - gets the number of days in a specified month of a year
2. `adjustDates` - updates the number of days in the drop down based on the selected month. Note: This simply appends/remove options instead of rebuilding from scratch.
3. `resetDates` - Reset the start month and year

I rewrote your code and tried to achieve the same logic you had in your demo code. Check out my demo and let me know if it works for you.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ByWhz/1/

**Full Code:**

```
$(function () {
    months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];

    /* Cachear selects */
    var $ld = $('select[name=llegada-dia]');
    var $lm = $('select[name=llegada-mes]');
    var $ly = $('select[name=llegada-ano]');
    var $sd = $('select[name=salida-dia]');
    var $sm = $('select[name=salida-mes]');
    var $sy = $('select[name=salida-ano]');

    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/1184359/297641
    function daysInMonth(month, year) {
        return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    }

    function adjustDates(selMonthDates, $sel) {
        var $options = $sel.find('option');
        var dates = $options.length;
        //append/remove missing dates
        if (dates > selMonthDates) { //remove
            $options.slice(selMonthDates).remove();
        } else { //append
            var dateOptions = [];
            for (var date = dates + 1; date <= selMonthDates; date++) {
                dateOptions.push('<option value="' + date + '">' + date + '</option>');
            }
            $sel.append(dateOptions.join('')); //reduces DOM call
        }
    }

    function resetDates() {
        $lm.val(function (i, v) {
            return (v == '') ? '0' : v;
        });
        $ly.val(function (i, v) {
            return (v == '') ? '2013' : v;
        });
    }

    var paintCals = function (day, month, year) {

        resetDates();

        //adjust start date
        var selMonthDates = daysInMonth((parseInt($lm.val(), 10) + 1), $ly.val());
        adjustDates(selMonthDates, $ld);

        //If current day selection > number of days in selected month then set the day to max allowed day
        if (day > selMonthDates) {
            day = selMonthDates;
            $ld.val(day); //update selection
        }

        //selected start date
        var selectedDate = new Date(year, month, day);

        //next day from start date
        var nextDay = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + 86400000);

        //lets build the end year drop down
        var tmpArr = [];
        for (var yrs = parseInt(nextDay.getFullYear(), 10); yrs <= 2020; yrs++) {
            tmpArr.push('<option value="' + yrs + '">' + yrs + '</option>');
        }
        $sy.empty().append(tmpArr.join('')); //set the YEARS
        //simply set the month
        $sm.val(nextDay.getMonth()); //set the month

        //adjust end date
        selMonthDates = daysInMonth(parseInt(nextDay.getMonth(), 10) + 1, nextDay.getFullYear());
        adjustDates(selMonthDates, $sd);

        $sd.val(nextDay.getDate()); //set the date

        $('#log').empty().append('Fecha: ' + selectedDate).append('<br>');
        $('#log').append('Siguiente: ' + nextDay);
    }

    $('.arrival select').on('change', function () {
        var ldia = $ld.val();
        var lmes = $lm.val();
        var lano = $ly.val();
        //console.log('lD/lM/lY:'+ldia,lmes,lano);

        var ldias = paintCals(ldia, lmes, lano);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 For the grouped updates of the `<option>`! I love how optimised is, allthough there is just one thing that it's not working properly.. If you choose january, then you are able to set it to 31; if then you chosse febrary (31) of febuary it sets it to 28 (as it should) but the departure date is set to 4 of march (instead of 1 of march), any idea?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Amazing catch. It failed because when you change the month (Feb - Jan), the day was still 31 so the `nextDate` calculation spilled the extra days resulting in `Mar 4th`. A simple fix is to add a condition to check if the selected month has fewer days than the day in the dropdown, if yes update days drop down to have max number of days for the selected month. I had typed a lot, but the fix is just 2 lines.

Comment: Yay! awesome! I can't find any problem so far! I wish I could vote again, I'll wait a little bit to see if there comes any better one but this one so far is the one I'm already implementing :D

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Am glad to know it is being used. Thank you and Good Luck.

Comment: Not sure if it's the desired behaviour, but that still allows to enter an end date that is smaller than the start date.

Answer (score 2):

**First:** manyDays fn needs to be:

```
var days_in_month = new Date(year, month+1, 0);
```

Because otherwise it goes back to previous month. You can read more about it in the comments of the most popular answer here: [Get number days in a specified month using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184334/get-number-days-in-a-specified-month-using-javascript)

**Second:** I removed

```
next_fecha.setMonth(fecha.getMonth() + (dia == dias_mes ? 1 : 0)   );
```

Since you already have

```
next_fecha.setDate(next_fecha.getDate()+1);
```

It switches month automatically in the end of month.

**Third:** this part had dia instead of month:

```
/* Actualizar meses salida */
        $sm.empty();
        for(var tmpmes = next_mes ; tmpmes < 12; tmpmes++){
    var doption = $('<option>').attr('value',tmpmes).text(months[tmpmes]);
            if(next_mes == tmpmes && next_mes != ''){
                console.log('fired');
      doption.attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
            $sm.append(doption);
        }
```

**---- ADDED ----**

**Fourth:** It also needs a check to see if Feb 31 exists. And if it is not, day should be the last day of that month. Otherwise the Date object didn't know what to do with the date and was giving wrong date.

Just needs to add a check:

```
var check_fecha = new Date( year, month );          
        check_mes = check_fecha.getMonth();
  check_anyo = check_fecha.getFullYear();
  var check_dias_mes = manyDays( check_mes, check_anyo );

  if(day > check_dias_mes)
    day = check_dias_mes;
```

Hope it solves it, check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/96qyH/13/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, as I comment in the answer I know that is a +-1 error, but I can't find the sense of it, I've seen your fiddle and it solves, as you say, first problem; but why is it also with  (2) months offset? Any clue?

Comment: It almost works, but by making few selections I was able to set 31 of FEB again... :(

Comment: OK, I think now it should work. Just needed an a few more checks.

Answer (score 2):

### If source code is required

I have found some answers for you! That might help you out! :) I have created a plugin too, but you won't need it to be the only answer. So here is what would help you. If you want to have a look at the code, you can get the source code here: https://github.com/the-vs-organisation/vdatetimepicker

### Solution to the first one

> Let days make sense with each month (Dont want 31 of feb selectable , ..)

For this issue, I used the value from the list of month as:

```
var month = $('#monthval').attr('id');
if(month == "February") {
  // hide the last few list items..
}
```

And then so on. You can see the source code in my plugin. You will find out how to interact with the other months too.

You can use `id` of the container as its value, as we won't use `select` Because you cannot style the `style` attribute. So you will require a custom created datetimepicker.

Disabing any of the item in the list won't be a good idea for the UI, so you might need to hide it. Hiding it won't bother UI or user himself. As the item won't be available he won't have to worry about the thing.

### Second one

I am not sure what you wanted in this one, so I will leave it instead of giving a vague answer.

### My Assumptions

If you want to get the time remaining or if you want to compare them, then you can use this:

```
var time = "some_string_of_time";
var curTime = new Date();
// now time to get the seconds between it..
var seconds = Math.floor((curTime - Time) / (1000));
// now write them..
if (seconds > 0 && seconds < 60) {// seconds..
    $('element') = seconds + " seconds ago";
}
```

### Hiding the values

> But some how the Date() object tell the right date, but both selectors show each set of Days for the previous one (For example, top 28 days happen in March instead of FEB)

This can be minimized in `select` as well as in my code. All you need to use is a simple class or id and on the click event for the month selector. Hide the excessive list items if any. Otherwise show. In my plugin, January and December will always have 31 days, Feb will have 28. It all depends on the list item selected in the Month dropdown. You can update the code in other div using jQuery.

### If you don't care about UI

If you don't want to style the UI, have you tried using the input tool?

```
<input type="date" name="datetime" />
```

This is a browser generated one. You can always use it when nothing else gets into handy.

### How to access data from my plugin.

You can always try to get the data from the `.vdtpckr` once you have the fields filled by using their ID for example:

```
var month = $('.vmonthval').attr('id');
```

This way, you can get the values from this.

If you need any thing more, comment below! :) Also try to check out the source code from github. You will get many ideas from the code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Allthoug even that it looks more reusable and extendable it's a little bit more complex than we need here; anyways +1 for your plugin

Comment: You can ask for the questions bro, that was just an example! I have added the code for you in my answer, which you might want to use..

Answer (score 1):

> Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if
>   values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as
>   the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will
>   be adjusted. E.g.  new Date(2013,13,1) is equivalent to new
>   Date(2014,1,1), both create a date for 2014-02-01.  Similarly for
>   other values: new Date(2013,2,1,0,70) is equivalent to new
>   Date(2013,2,1,1,10) which both create a date for 2013-03-01T01:10:00.

That's from the Note for date constructor at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

The issue is with the following function

```
var manyDays = function( month, year ){
  var fecha = new Date(year, (month) , 0);
  return fecha.getDate();
}
```

When you use 0 as the date you get the previous month

for example

```
var date1 = new Date(2013,2,0)
console.log(date1.getMonth()); // will print 1 = Feb

var date2 = new Date(2013,2,1)
console.log(date2.getMonth()); // will print 2 = March

var date3 = new Date(2013,2,32)
console.log(date3.getMonth()); // will print 3 = April
```

I don't know of any proper way to get the number of days of a month in Javascript. A know hack is to modify your `manyDays` method like this.

```
var manyDays = function( month, year ){
  // Note: month + 1
  var fecha = new Date(year, month+1 , 0);
  return fecha.getDate();
}
```

You dont need to do the following

```
next_fecha.setDate(next_fecha.getDate() + 1); 
next_fecha.setMonth(fecha.getMonth() + (dia == dias_mes ? 1 : 0)   ); 
next_fecha.setFullYear(fecha.getFullYear() + (mes == 12 ? 1 : 0)  );
```

It can be replace with just

```
next_fecha.setDate(next_fecha.getDate() + 1);
```

Because adding a day to the date object will update date,month,year etc appropriately.

**Answer to the problem in comment**

The for loop handling the months in this [version](http://jsfiddle.net/96qyH/11) has an error. You are using the wrong variable. Change `dia` and `tmpdia` to `next_mes` and `tmpmes` respectively.

it should be like this

```
$sm.empty();
for(var tmpmes = next_mes ; tmpmes < 12; tmpmes++){
  var doption = $('<option>').attr('value',tmpmes).text(months[tmpmes]);
  if(next_mes == tmpmes && next_mes != ''){
    doption.attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
  $sm.append(doption);
}
```

The following is the updated version with the above problem fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/96qyH/14/

Comment: Thanks for you anser, I did the suggested changes and seems to work; but if 31 of march is choosen then the departure date is set to 1 of DEC, any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/96qyH/11/

Comment: I think it's safer to use
    var fecha = new Date(year, (month + 1) % 12 , 0);

Answer (score 1):

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sumitk2209/BqVu6/) by me, hope this works for you

For HTML

```
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <fieldset id='dbOne'>
        <legend>Start Date</legend>
        <label for="yearOne">Year</label>
        <select name="yearOne" id="yearOne" title="Year" class='year'></select>
        <label for="monthOne">Month</label>
        <select name="monthOne" id="monthOne" title="Month"  class='month'></select>

        <label for="dayOne">Day</label>
        <select name="dayOne" id="dayOne" title="Day"  class='day'></select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='dbTwo'>
        <legend>End Date</legend>
        <label for="yearTwo">Year</label>
        <select name="yearTwo" id="yearTwo" title="Year" class='year'></select>
        <label for="monthTwo">Month</label>
        <select name="monthTwo" id="monthTwo" title="Month"  class='month'></select>
        <label for="dayTwo">Day</label>
        <select name="dayTwo" id="dayTwo" title="Day"  class='day'></select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

AND JS

```
  $(function () {
        // get days in month
        function daysInMonth(month, year) {

            month = parseInt(month,10)+1;
            month=month.toString();
            return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        }
        //creates an array of number, a = array size, b starting num
        var numberArray = function (a, b) {
            c = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                c[i] = i + b;
            }
            return c;
        };
        //generates numeric drop down
        function createOptions(parent, options) {
            var l = options.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                var val = options[i];
                var text = options[i];
                var node = document.createElement("option");
                node.textContent = text;
                node.value = val;
                if(i===0) node.selected='selected';
                parent.appendChild(node);

            }
        }
        //generates drop down with numeric value string text
        function getOptionFromMap(parent, map) {
            for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
                var x = map[i];
                var val = x.key;
                var text = x.val;
                var node = document.createElement("option");
                node.textContent = text;
                node.value = val;
                if(i===0) node.selected='selected';
                parent.appendChild(node);
            }

        }
        var years = numberArray(20, 2000);
        var days = numberArray(31, 1);
        var months = [{
            key: 00,
            val: "jan"
        }, {
            key: 01,
            val: "feb"
        }, {
            key: 02,
            val: "mar"
        }, {
            key: 03,
            val: "apr"
        }, {
            key: 04,
            val: "may"
        }, {
            key: 05,
            val: "jun"
        }, {
            key: 06,
            val: "jul"
        }, {
            key: 07,
            val: "aug"
        }, {
            key: 08,
            val: "sep"
        }, {
            key: 09,
            val: "oct"
        }, {
            key: 10,
            val: "nov"
        }, {
            key: 11,
            val: "dec"
        }];
        createOptions(document.getElementById('dayOne'), days);
        createOptions(document.getElementById('dayTwo'), days);
        createOptions(document.getElementById('yearOne'), years);
        createOptions(document.getElementById('yearTwo'), years);
        getOptionFromMap(document.getElementById('monthOne'), months);
        getOptionFromMap(document.getElementById('monthTwo'), months);

        $(".year,.month").bind({
            change:function(){
                var dInMonth = daysInMonth($('.month',$(this).parent()).val(), $('.year',$(this).parent()).val());
                $('.day',$(this).parent()).children().each(function(){

                    var cEle = $(this);
                    var cValue = parseInt(cEle.html(),10);
                    if(!cEle.is(':disabled') && (cValue>dInMonth)) {
                        cEle.attr({disabled:true});
                    } else if(cEle.is(':disabled') && (cValue<=dInMonth)) {
                        cEle.attr({disabled:false});
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $('select',$('#dbOne,#dbTwo')).bind({
            change:function(){
                var dBoxOne = $('#dbOne');
                var dBoxtwo = $('#dbTwo');
                var dtOne = getDateString(dBoxOne);
                var dOne = new Date(dtOne.y,dtOne.m,dtOne.d);
                var dtTwo = getDateString(dBoxtwo);
                var dTwo = new Date(dtTwo.y,dtTwo.m,dtTwo.d);
                if(dOne>dTwo) {
                    var nextDay = parseInt(dtOne.d,10)+1;
                    //alert('a');
                    dTwo = new Date(dtOne.y,dtOne.m,nextDay.toString());
                    setDate(dBoxtwo,dTwo);
                } else {

                }
            }
        });

        function getDateString(dateBox){
            var year = $('.year',dateBox).val();
            var month = $('.month',dateBox).val();
            var day = $('.day',dateBox).val();
            var da = year+"/"+month+"/"+day;
            var d = {y:year,m:month,d:day};
            return d;

        }

        function setDate(dateBox,dateObj){
            var year = dateObj.getFullYear();
            var month = dateObj.getMonth();
            var day = dateObj.getDate();

            $('.year',dateBox).val(year);
            $('.month',dateBox).val(month);
            $('.day',dateBox).val(day);

        }



    });
```

Comment: One glitch I found - you can put the second date day equal to the first date day - for instance, if first date is 2001-feb-27, you can put in 2001-feb-27 for second date

Comment: If requirement is that or changes to that it can be fixed by commenting two line and changing one parameter like this                                  if(dOne>dTwo) {
                //var nextDay = parseInt(dtOne.d,10)+1;
                //alert('a');
                //dTwo = new Date(dtOne.y,dtOne.m,nextDay.toString());
                setDate(dBoxtwo,dOne);
            }

Comment: Thans sumit for your effort, allthough we need it to be as much as posible in jQuery, +1!

Comment: This implementation is using jQuery, but there was need for plain javascript for date calculations. The javascript part which generates dropBoxes can be replaced with plain HTML or with server side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

## **Here is my effort - Covers all Edge Cases**

It is a robust well-tested date picker by now and answers the following questions:

> - Let days make sense with each month (Dont want 31 of feb selectable ,    ..)
> - Set next thay from START to the END selector
>
> ...
>
> But some how the Date() object tell the right date, but both selectors
>   show each set of Days for the previous one (For example, top 28 days
>   happen in March instead of FEB)

If you look below I take care of all the above and more using small modular functions:

- **maxDay()** - given a month and year, it returns the max numbers of days in that month for that year
- **createAry()** - given min, max and optional array of values returns an
  array from min to max or portion of values array between min and max
  indices
- **days()** - given min day and month and year uses *maxDay()* to get max day.  Uses *createAry()* to return an array ready to use to populate day *<select>* options
- **months()** - given min month and an array of month text values (like 'jan', 'feb', etc.) uses *createAry()* to return an array ready to use to populate month *<select>* options
- **years()** - given min year uses *MAXYEAR* constant and *createAry()* to return an array ready to use to populate year *<select>* options
- **updateSelectOptions()** - given a jQuery DOM *<select>* element, an array of option texts from *day()*, *month()* or *year()* and selected option index, empties then fills *<select>*; with array values and selects appropriate option.
- **updateTos()** - updates the *End Date* rolling past *Start Date* if necessary and doing min month, day and year calculations based on *Start Date* values.  Calls *updateSelectOptions()* for month, day and year giving jQuery *<select>* DOM element and arrays returned by *month()*, *day()* and *year()* to update *<select>* options with appropriate text values and selecting correct current option.
- **update()** - updates either start or end date internally with *new Date()* using month, day and year from selected *<select>* options.  For *Start Date*, calls *updateSelectOptions()* using *days()* and *maxDay()* to limit days according to month and year and select current option.  Calls *updateTos()* to update *End Date* and its *<select>* options.

**jsFiddle:**

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KwG89/)

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <fieldset class="dateField">
        <legend>Start Date</legend>
        <label for="fromMonth">Month</label>
        <select id="fromMonth" class='monthSelect'></select>
        <label for="fromDay">Day</label>
        <select id="fromDay" class='daySelect'></select>
        <label for="fromYear">Year</label>
        <select id="fromYear" class='yearSelect'></select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="dateField">
        <legend>End Date</legend>
        <label for="toMonth">Month</label>
        <select id="toMonth" class='monthSelect'></select>
        <label for="toDay">Day</label>
        <select id="toDay" class='daySelect'></select>
        <label for="toYear">Year</label>
        <select id="toYear" class='yearSelect'></select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<input type="button" id="reset" class="resetButton" value="Reset" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
'use strict';

var fromDay = $('#fromDay'),
    fromMonth = $('#fromMonth'),
    fromYear = $('#fromYear'),
    toDay = $('#toDay'),
    toMonth = $('#toMonth'),
    toYear = $('#toYear'),
    reset = $('#reset'),
    CURDATE = new Date(),
    curFromDate,
    curToDate,
    MINYEAR = 2000,
    NUMYEARS = 40,
    MAXYEAR = MINYEAR + NUMYEARS - 1,
    MAXDATE = new Date(MAXYEAR, 11, 31),
    MONTHS = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];

function maxDay(params) { // {month, year}

    params.month = params.month || 0;
    params.year = params.year || MINYEAR;

    return new Date(params.year, (params.month - 0) + 1, 0).getDate();
}

function createAry(params) { // { min, max, values }

    var i,
        ary = [];

    params.values = params.values || [];

    if (params.values.length !== 0) {
        return params.values.slice(params.min, params.max + 1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < params.max - params.min + 1; i++) {
        ary[i] = params.min + i;
    }

    return ary;
}

function days(params) { // {minDay, month, year}

    var max;

    params.month = params.month || 0;
    params.year = params.year || MINYEAR;

    max = maxDay({
        month: params.month,
        year: params.year
    });

    params.minDay = params.minDay || 1;

    return createAry({
        min: params.minDay,
        max: max
    });
}

function months(params) { // {minMonth, months}

    params.minMonth = params.minMonth || 0;

    return createAry({
        min: params.minMonth,
        max: 11,
        values: MONTHS
    })
}

function years(params) { // {minYear}

    params.minYear = params.minYear || MINYEAR;

    return createAry({
        min: params.minYear,
        max: MAXYEAR
    });
}

function updateSelectOptions(params) { // {select, options, current]

    params.select.empty();

    params.options.forEach(function (e, i) {
        params.select.append($('<option></option>').prop("selected", i === params.current).text(e));
    });

}

function updateTos() {

    var minDay = 1,
        minMonth = 0,
        minYear = curFromDate.getFullYear();

    if (curToDate <= curFromDate) {
        curToDate = new Date(curFromDate.getFullYear(), curFromDate.getMonth(), curFromDate.getDate() + 1);

        minYear = curToDate.getFullYear();

        if (minYear === curFromDate.getFullYear()) {
            minMonth = curToDate.getMonth();
        }
        if (curFromDate.getMonth() === curToDate.getMonth()) {
            minDay = curToDate.getDate();
        }
    } else if (curFromDate.getFullYear() === curToDate.getFullYear()) {
        minMonth = curFromDate.getMonth();
        if (curFromDate.getMonth() === curToDate.getMonth()) {
            minDay = curFromDate.getDate() + 1;
        }
    } else if (curFromDate.getDate() === 31 && curFromDate.getMonth() === 11) {
        minYear++;
    }

    updateSelectOptions({
        select: toDay,
        options: days({
            minDay: minDay,
            month: curToDate.getMonth(),
            year: curToDate.getFullYear()
        }),
        current: curToDate.getDate() - minDay
    });
    updateSelectOptions({
        select: toMonth,
        options: months({
            minMonth: minMonth,
            months: MONTHS
        }),
        current: curToDate.getMonth() - minMonth
    });
    updateSelectOptions({
        select: toYear,
        options: years({
            minYear: minYear
        }),
        current: curToDate.getFullYear() - minYear
    });
}

function update(params) { // {toOrFrom}

    var day,
        month,
        year,
        max,
        date;

    if (params.toOrFrom === 'from') {
        day = fromDay.find("option:selected").text();
        month = MONTHS.indexOf(fromMonth.find("option:selected").text());
        year = fromYear.find("option:selected").text();
    } else {
        day = toDay.find("option:selected").text();
        month = MONTHS.indexOf(toMonth.find("option:selected").text());
        year = toYear.find("option:selected").text();
    }
    max = maxDay({
        month: month,
        year: year
    });

    if (day > max) {
        day = max;
    }
    date = new Date(year, month, day);

    if (params.toOrFrom === 'from') {
        if (date >= MAXDATE) {
            alert('The date you entered is later than the latest allowed date.  Please enter a different date.');

            fromDay.prop("selectedIndex", curFromDate.getDate() - 1);
            fromMonth.prop("selectedIndex", curFromDate.getMonth());
            fromYear.prop("selectedIndex", curFromDate.getFullYear() - MINYEAR);

            return;
        }
        curFromDate = date;

        updateSelectOptions({
            select: fromDay,
            options: days({
                minDay: 1,
                month: month,
                year: year
            }),
            current: day - 1
        });

    } else {
        curToDate = date;
    }
    updateTos();
}

function onFromChange() {
    update({
        toOrFrom: 'from'
    });
}

function onToChange() {
    update({
        toOrFrom: 'to'
    });
}

function init() {
    curFromDate = new Date(CURDATE.getFullYear(), CURDATE.getMonth(), CURDATE.getDate());
    curToDate = new Date(CURDATE.getFullYear(), CURDATE.getMonth(), CURDATE.getDate());

    updateSelectOptions({
        select: fromDay,
        options: days({
            minDay: 1,
            month: curFromDate.getMonth(),
            year: curFromDate.getFullYear()
        }),
        current: curFromDate.getDate() - 1
    });
    updateSelectOptions({
        select: fromMonth,
        options: months({
            months: MONTHS
        }),
        current: curFromDate.getMonth()
    });
    updateSelectOptions({
        select: fromYear,
        options: years({
            minYear: MINYEAR
        }),
        current: curFromDate.getFullYear() - MINYEAR
    });

    updateTos();
}

fromDay.change(onFromChange);
fromMonth.change(onFromChange);
fromYear.change(onFromChange);
toDay.change(onToChange);
toMonth.change(onToChange);
toYear.change(onToChange);
reset.click(init);

init();
```

**CSS:**

```
fieldset.dateField {
    width: 375px;
}

select.daySelect {
    width: 45px;
    margin: 5px 10px 0 0;
}

select.monthSelect {
    width: 55px;
    margin: 5px 10px 0 10px;
}

select.yearSelect {
    width: 65px;
    margin: 5px 10px 0 0;
}

input.resetButton {
    margin: 10px 20px 0 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/XvEzz/. I'm sorry for having rewritten your code entirely but that was an easier way for me to figure out the issue. The code below should help you to resolve your problem. It's located at line 24 and executed when the user chooses a month. I've added some comments here in order to explain the process. The basic idea is to set the day to 1 temporarily, then to restore last selected day if possible :

```
// saves last selected day 
day = date.getDate();
// sets day to 1 in order to prevent the month from changing
date.setDate(1);
// sets selected month
date.setMonth(this.selectedIndex);
// retrieves number of days for this month
days = getDays(date);
// restores last selected day if included in this month
if (day <= days) date.setDate(day);
// refreshes days options
feedCombo(0, getRange(1, days));
// refreshes selected day
$select.eq(idx - 1).val(date.getDate());
```