# D3.js - get number of days for a certain month

Tags: date, datetime, d3.js

I'm using [D3.js (v3)](https://github.com/d3/d3) to plot a time-series graph and I'm trying to figure out the amount of ticks I need for a given month (ie, days). From what I can make of [the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Intervals.md#month), `d3.time-month` should return something from 28 to 31 days, which is what I want, but for some reason I'm obviously missing, I can't seem to get the number I need.

Can anyone help?

This is what I've got so far:

```
console.log(date); // Fri Jul 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (WEST)

monthDays = d3.time.month(date);

console.log(currentMonth+" has "+monthDays+" days."); // July has Fri Jul 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (WEST) days.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1184334/6210816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misreading the documentation on [intervals](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Intervals.md#_interval) : the number of days in  the intervals used by [`d3.time.month`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Intervals.md#month)  have a length between 28 and 31 but the functions are defined as

> *`interval(date)`*
>
> Alias for `interval.floor(date)`. [...]

and

> *`interval.floor(date)`*
>
> Rounds down the specified date, returning the latest time interval
>   before or equal to date. [...]

Basically, `d3.time.month(date)` will return the first day of the month at midnight, not the number of days in that month.

---

How to get the number of days then? As far as I can tell, D3 does not expose a way to get the length of the month  for a given date. You could of course get the range of days for a given month and extract its length:

```
var date = new Date(2016, 01, 02); // 2016-02-02
console.log(
    d3.time.days(d3.time.month(date), d3.time.month.ceil(date)).length
)
```

or probably more efficiently use plain JS like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185804/1071630 :

```
var date = new Date(2016, 01, 02); // 2016-02-02
console.log(
    new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate()
)
```

```js
var date = new Date(2016, 01, 02);

console.log(
  d3.time.days(d3.time.month(date), d3.time.month.ceil(date)).length
)

console.log(
 new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you came here looking for a quick way to find the number of days between two d3.Date objects, check out [D3-Time](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#interval_count), specifically the `interval.count()` method.