# Get the last date of month in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, format

In php we can get the last date of a month by formatting it as `('Y-m-t')`. If we format 2017-01-01 as ('Y-m-t') it gives 2017-01-31. Is there a way to do this from javascript? How can I get the last date of the given month. My input is 'Jan-2017'. How can I format this into 2017-01-31?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184334/get-number-days-in-a-specified-month-using-javascript