# jQuery - Display all dates (in numbers) in current month

Tags: jquery

How can I display all dates in a month @ Below format

> All days in current month: **1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ... 31**

**HTML**

```
<div id="allDates"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var allDates = d.getDate();
    $('#allDates').html('All days in current month:' + '<br>' + allDates);
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185068/5743676 try this

Answer (score 3):

Using the date constructor generate the first date of a month and last date of month and then push all dates in an array and display it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var today = new Date(),
    firstDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1),
    lastDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0),
    result = [];

    while(firstDay <= lastDay){
      result.push(firstDay.getDate());
      firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1);
    }

    $('#allDates').html('All days in current month:' + '<br>' + result.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="allDates"></div>
```

Using this stackoverflow [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1184359/4758494)

```js
function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var today = new Date(),
    days = daysInMonth(today.getMonth() + 1, today.getFullYear()),
    result = Array.from({length:days}, (_,i) => i+1).join(',');
    $('#allDates').html('All days in current month:' + '<br>' + result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="allDates"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var d = new Date();
var LastDay = 32 - new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 32).getDate();
var Output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < LastDay - 1; i++) {
    Output += (i + 1) + ", ";
}
document.write(Output);
```

Comment: populate it by object then stringify it would distinguish that trailing comma

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var d = new Date();
    var numberOfDays = getDaysInMonth(d.getMonth() + 1, d.getFullYear())
    var allDates = ''
  for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfDays; i++) {
    allDates += i + ' '
  }

  $('#allDates').html('All days in current month:' + '<br>' + allDates);
});
function getDaysInMonth(month,year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another twist, get the last day of the month and then loop to get the output as

```
var getDaysInMonth = function(month,year) {
  // Here January is 1 based
  //Day 0 is the last day in the previous month
 return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
// Here January is 0 based
// return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  var d = new Date();
    var lastdayOfmonth = getDaysInMonth(d.getMonth() , d.getFullYear())
    var allDates = ''
  for (var i = 1; i <= lastdayOfmonth; i++) {
    allDates += i + ' '
  }

  $('#allDates').html('Current month dates :' + '<br>' + allDates);
});
```

Please refer this link :- https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-3.php