# Creating a date picker and loading the appropriate amount of days in a given month

Tags: c#, javascript, date, calendar, datepicker

Basically, I want three drop down lists in my registration form. One for year, month and days.

How do I make sure that when someone chooses a year and month, I load the right amount of days? For example if someone chooses February on a leap year, I would have to show 28 days instead of 29 and so on and so forth.

I *could* do an Ajax request when someone picks a month and on my server fetch how many days are in `Year X - Month Y`, but this would make it seem weird, right?

How do you suggest I do this? Is there some mathematical formula I can apply in local javascript so it loads the days correctly without going back to the server for the day collection?

Comment: use a pre-written one and save all your headaches .. for example - >http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ or http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/date-picker-v4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to determine the number of days in a month with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315760/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use this -> excellent JavaScript date picker -> http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/date-picker-v4/

Saves you the hassle of browser testing / code writing / number of days in a month / leapyear work ....

Dont re-invent the wheel :-)