# Getting days in a month using JavaScript:Issue

Tags: javascript, browser, client

I'm trying to get the days of a month using JavaScript and face a problem. I'm currently using a solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315760/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-with-javascript).

Here's my code :

```
 function getDays(month,year){

    if(month=="" || year==""|| year=="--Select--"){

        document. getElementById("days"). innerHTML ="";
        return;
    }

    var months= new Array();
    alert("Month in Function"+month);// To test.
    alert("Year in function"+year);
    months[0]="January";
    months[1]="February";
    months[2]="March";
    months[3]="April";
    months[4]="May";
    months[5]="June";
    months[6]="July";
    months[7]="August";
    months[8]="September";
    months[9]="October";
    months[10]="November";
    months[11]="December";
    var index=months.indexOf(month);
    alert("Index used"+index);
      var datebase = new Date(year,index,1); //nb: month = zerobased
      datebase.setDate(datebase.getDate()-1);

            // Also tried database=new Date(year, index, 0).getDate();


    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML =datebase.getDate();// This value is skewed.

}
```

I get weird values for the days of the month for example, April 2012 gives me 31 days and March 2011 gives me 28 days. Any help on what I could be messing up here would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building the date using `new Date(year,index,1)`, which gives e.g. the 1st of March if you pass `"March"`. You then subtract one day to get the 28st of February. Then you say that *March* has 28 days. This is a wrong conclusion, obviously.

You'd need to build using:

```
new Date(year, index + 1, 1);
// so, build e.g. 1 April when "March" is passed, then
// subtract one to get last day of March
```

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago I have to do the same thing - get the number of days that a month have in a given year. There are a lot of solutions, but the this one I think is the shortest and nicest one.

```
 function DaysInMonth(Month,Year){
     return (32-new Date(Year,Month,32).getDate());     
 }
```

The function has two parameters:

1. Month - this is a integer value from 0 to 11, where 0 indicates
   January and 11 - December
2. Year - the year

Try it:

```
  DaysInMonth(1,2012)
  DaysInMonth(2,2012)
```