# enable first and last sunday of every month jquery calendar

Tags: jquery

As I am new to jquery and I need to display first and last sunday in my website.I got this code from stackoverflow but it enables all sundays so please help me

```
function enableSUNDAYS(date) {
var day = date.getDay();
return [(day == 0), ''];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work;

```
function enableFirstAndLastSunday(date) {
    var lastDayInMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
    var isSunday = date.getDay() == 0;
    var isFirstDayOfMonth = date.getDate() <= 7;
    var isLastDayOfMonth = date.getDate() > lastDayInMonth - 7;

    return [isSunday && (isFirstDayOfMonth || isLastDayOfMonth), '']; 
}
```

It checks that the date is a Sunday (using the same code you provided), but also checks that it occurs within either the first 7 days of the month, or the last 7. The calculation of `lastDayInMonth` is based on [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315767/444991).

You can see a demo of this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/6ZpfE/1/) (thanks [Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a) for the demo).