# Populate array with number of weeks based on the given month

Tags: jquery

Here's what I want but when I searched the net no answer came up which eventually saddens me. Now here's what I want to happen

I have a drop down which populates the months. What I want is whenever I pick 1 month in month dropdown, I want the other drop down which I will cal period drop down to populate (1,2,3,4) if the picked month in month drop down has 4 weeks and (1,2,3,4,5) if the picked month has 5 weeks.

I don't know where to start and totally have no idea.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: A month has 28-31 days. The most weeks any month can have is 4.4285715. You need to clarify the question.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "I don't know where to start"? Do you know how to write anything in javascript at all?

Comment: how about getting the [daysInMonth](http://stackoverflow.com/a/315767/1232526)/4?

Comment: Actually I'm more than a php and APSX guy. I totally dont know what jquery is. And with regards to my question, I if I click January then the 2nd dropdown must be populated by 1,2,3,4,5 since it has 5 weeks.

Comment: week in which sense. According to you how many week there should be in  August 2014. 5,6 or 4.42

Comment: In August 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Found it guys. Thanks anyways for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first create two select boxes as shown below:

```
<select id="month">
    <option>Select Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
<select>
<select id="weeks" style="display:none;"></select>
```

In your Jquery code you need to get selected value of your month dropdown then use function `weekCount` to count weeks in a given month with respect to given year. and then simply populate the options in another dropdown.

```
function weekCount(year, month_number) {

    // month_number is in the range 1..12

    var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number-1, 1);
    var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number, 0);

    var used = firstOfMonth.getDay() + lastOfMonth.getDate();

    return Math.ceil( used / 7);
}
$('#month').change(function(){
    var selectedMonth = $(this).val();
    if(selectedMonth != "") {
        var totalWeeks = weekCount(2014, selectedMonth),
            optionsHtml = '';
        for(var i=1; i<=totalWeeks; i++) {
            optionsHtml += '<option>' + i + '</option>';   
        }
        $('#weeks').html(optionsHtml);
        $('#weeks').show();
    } else {
     $('#weeks').hide();   
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/8cywttvz/)**

Comment: What If I want to concatenate something in the result `optionsHtml += '<option>' + i + '</option>';` like for example I want to concatenate 1st letter of the month

Comment: Get the first letter from the selected option: `firstLetter =$(this).find('option:selected').text().substring(0, 1)` and append it into the loop like this: optionsHtml += '<option>' + firstLetter + i + '</option>'; [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/8cywttvz/3/)