# Programming a birthdate SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my form, I have three select elements, which are Month, Day, and Year. What I'm achieving is, if the user selects a month, the days must match according to what month the user has selected.

For example, `January(1-31), May(1-30), February(1-28)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to determine the number of days in a month with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315760/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-with-javascript)

Comment: Use `<input type='date'>` instead..

Comment: jquery ui has a very nice calendar widget as well

Comment: ... note that May actually has 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetDays(year, month) {
    var isLeapYear = ((year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || year % 400 === 0);

    return [31, (isLeapYear ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];
}
```

Call `GetDays` function on change event of `month` selection `control`

Comment: Where should I put the `GetDays` function? Inside the `month` selection?

Comment: `<select id="DDLMonth" onchange="DDLMonth_Change(this)">

</select>

function DDLMonth_Change(control){
var totalDays = GetDays(2015,10);
//fill days dropdown
}`