# get number of days in the CURRENT month using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

For my website I am trying to get the number of days for the CURRENT month for a certain feature.

I have seen examples online that get days of a specified month, however I need to get the days of the CURRENT month and find how many days are left of that month.

Here is the code I managed to put together:

```
function myFunction() {
    var today = new Date();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    console.log(month);
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: So, use the example online, and pass the current month to it...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to determine the number of days in a month with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315760/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-with-javascript)

Comment: And what exactly isn’t working with this code? Your code only gets the current month. Use it with whatever function you found that gets the number of days.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
function daysInThisMonth() {
  var now = new Date();
  return new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();
}
```

Comment: so how would i edit this to make it functional showing the days in the month?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This function returns the number of days in the current month.

Comment: Maybe you need help logging it? E.g. `console.log(daysInThisMonth());`?

Comment: sorry let me reword it, I need to find the days remaining of the current month.

Comment: Oh, that would be `daysInThisMonth() - (new Date()).getDate()`.

Comment: thank you so much this worked perfectly! being a newbie and having great help is hard to come by thank you

Comment: Can you please explain in brief the working behind this?

Comment: @bubble-cord new Date(2019, 7, 0): 0 => gives u the Date of the last day of the month (Wed Jul 31 2019).  Then Date(2019, 7, 0).getDate(); returns you the day of that Date as integer (31).

Comment: @bubble-cord mdn rocks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 4):

based on the answer from this post:
[What is the best way to determine the number of days in a month with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315760/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-with-javascript)

It should be easy to modify this to work for the current month
Here's your code and the function from the other post:

```
function myFunction() {
    var today = new Date();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    console.log(daysInMonth(month + 1, today.getFullYear()))
}

function daysInMonth(month,year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

myFunction();
```

Note that the function `date.getMonth()` returns a zero-based number, so just add 1 to normalize.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for thank you. any idea how to figure out how many days left in the current month?

Comment: Sure. Check out https://jsfiddle.net/8023vhfs/ Tell me if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Get number of day's in current month: single line of code.

```
var daysInCurrentMonth=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate()
console.log(daysInCurrentMonth);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var numberOfDaysOnMonth = function() {
    let h = new Date()
    h.setMonth(h.getMonth() + 1)
    h.setDate(h.getDate() - 1)
    return h.getDate()
};
```