# calendar in letter shape

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a calendar in a specific letter shape (in this case in shape of 'S')

I have applied some CSS.

Here is my script:

```js
const calendarContainer = document.getElementById('safety-calendar');
const daysInMonth = 29;
const sShapePattern = [
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
];
let dayCount = 1;

function generateSCalendar() {
    calendarContainer.innerHTML = '';
    sShapePattern.forEach((val, index) => {
        const dayElement = document.createElement('div');
        dayElement.classList.add('calendar-day');
        if (val === 1 && dayCount <= daysInMonth) {
            dayElement.textContent = dayCount++;
            dayElement.classList.add('bg-green-300', 'text-green-800');
            dayElement.onclick = function() {
                this.classList.toggle('bg-red-300');
                this.classList.toggle('text-red-800');
            };
        } else {
            dayElement.classList.add('hidden-day');
        }
        calendarContainer.appendChild(dayElement);
    });
}

generateSCalendar();
```

```css
.calendar-day {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 2px;
    user-select: none;
}
.hidden-day {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    gap: 2px;
}
```

```html
<section id="safety-calendar"></section>
```

The problems:

- I cannot make it to show current month days for example today is February which means I should have 29 sqr into the calendar.
- With the current code I have only 18.
  Where am mistaken?
  Is my way correct?
  Note: I am also using TailwindCSS in this is something important

Comment: It would probably help if you added to the question a sample of what an S calendar is meant to be. Nothing fancy, just type the numbers yourself in a code section.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add your grid style to the root element, and your matrix doesn't have enough `1`s for the whole month:

```js
const calendarContainer = document.getElementById('safety-calendar');
const daysInMonth = 29;
const sShapePattern = [
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
];
let dayCount = 1;

function generateSCalendar() {
    calendarContainer.innerHTML = '';
    sShapePattern.forEach((val, index) => {
        const dayElement = document.createElement('div');
        dayElement.classList.add('calendar-day');
        if (val === 1 && dayCount <= daysInMonth) {
            dayElement.textContent = dayCount++;
            dayElement.classList.add('bg-green-300', 'text-green-800');
            dayElement.onclick = function() {
                this.classList.toggle('bg-red-300');
                this.classList.toggle('text-red-800');
            };
        } else {
            dayElement.classList.add('hidden-day');
        }
        calendarContainer.appendChild(dayElement);
    });
}

generateSCalendar();
```

```css
.calendar-day {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 2px;
    user-select: none;
}
.hidden-day {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 30px);
    gap: 2px;
}

.bg-green-300 { background-color: green }
```

```html
<section id="safety-calendar" class="grid-container"></section>
```

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious but you can also fill in the rest of the days after the loop of the matrix, it doesn't have to be mutated.

Comment: is there a way to make it also automatically fill based on the month? 
I mean for example Feb is 29 but March is  31

Comment: @Qbasix [Get numbers of day in current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446725/get-number-of-days-in-the-current-month-using-javascript)