# EOMONTH equivalent in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script that doing some date manipulation and I need to know how many days between current date and end of the month.

I've already got a function that I can put two dates into and it'll return the number of days between the two dates.

I'm looking for an equivalent of EOMONTH in scripts so I can return the date of the last day of any given month
(Hope that makes sense)

All I've been able to come up with so far is adding a day to the date until it becomes a new month and running a counter whilst doing so, but this just seems a really silly way of doing it.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315760/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-with-javascript.

Comment: perfect thanks! Don't know why my search didn't come up with that

Answer (score 1):

```
function daysInMonth(m=0) {
  return new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),m+1,0).getDate();
}
```

Comment: A very clever way of getting the EOM.