# How do I set up an apps script trigger to email a Google form at the end of every month?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created the following Apps Script to automatically email a Google form at the end of every month.  I'm getting the error "Script function not found: sendEmail" and I don't know enough about any of this to figure out how to fix it and my googling has been fruitless.  Any help is appreciated!!

```
function monthlyEmailTrigger() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(8)
      .everyDays(1)
      .create();
}

function myTriggerFunction()
{
  var today = new Date();
  var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);

  if(today.getDate() == lastDayOfMonth.getDate() )
  {
    function sendEmail() {
    GmailApp.sendEmail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Monthly Form',  'Please complete this form (form URL here).');
  }
}
}
```

Comment: `sendEmail` is only within the scope of `myTriggerFunction`.  I'm not sure if you have 2 triggers, `sendEmail` created by `monthlyEmailTrigger` and `myTriggerFunction`.  I believe what you want is to create 1 trigger.  Replace `ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')` with `ScriptApp.newTrigger('myTriggerFunction')`.

Answer (score 0):

The ClockTriggerBuilder Class already has [`onMonthDay()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#onMonthDay(Integer)) to run every `x` day of the month, so you have a few other approaches.

If you don't mind sending the email on the first day of every month you can just set `onMonthDay(1)`

```js
function monthlyEmailTrigger() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
      .timeBased()
      .onMonthDay(1)
      .create();
}

function sendEmail() {
    GmailApp.sendEmail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Monthly Form',  'Please complete this form (form URL here).');
}
```

If you really need to run it on the last day, `onMonthDay` takes values up to 31, but I didn't find any documentation that would confirm whether or not this would work on months with fewer days, so just to be safe you can also create a trigger that runs on the first day of the month, to calculate the last day and set a trigger for that day.

```
function triggerCreator(){ // run once to create the trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('monthlyTrigger')
      .timeBased()
      .onMonthDay(1) //the trigger will runs every 1st day of the month
      .create()
}

function monthlyTrigger(){
  let today = new Date()
  let month = today.getMonth()+1
  let year = today.getFullYear()

  let lastday = daysInMonth(today.getMonth()+1, year) // calculates last day of the current month
  
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
      .timeBased()
      .atDate(year, month, lastday) //sets the trigger to run the last day of the current month
      .create()
}

function daysInMonth (month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

function sendEmail() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Monthly Form',  'Please complete this form (form URL here).');
}
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315760/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-with-javascript) for the `daysInMonth()` function.